# Dell vostro 3560 no wifi

Tags: 12.04, wireless, dell-vostro

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I install BCM43142 wireless drivers for Dell Vostro 3460/3560?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/175104/how-do-i-install-bcm43142-wireless-drivers-for-dell-vostro-3460-3560)

I just bought new Dell Vostro 3560 with Ubuntu 11.10 and when I upgareded it to 12.04 LTS I lost my wifi card. System doesnt see my wifi cards so im not able to install any drivers, etc.

Comment: Have you checked the wireless hardware switch?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! We need more hardware information to help you, can you look at [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/14008/i-have-a-hardware-detection-problem-what-logs-do-i-need-to-look-into) and then edit your question adding the information.

Comment: The same problem. WIFI doesn't work on 12.04, but worked on 11.10 that came preinstalled.
I switched to Win7 because of it :(

Answer (score 0):

In terminal run

```
lspci |grep Network
```

If output is similar to this:

```
Network controller: Broadcom Corporatrion Device 4365 (rev 01)
```

or another Broadcom chipset 43xx series, follow this solution:

- [How do I install BCM43142 wireless drivers for Dell Vostro 3460/3560?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/175104/how-do-i-install-bcm43142-wireless-drivers-for-dell-vostro-3460-3560/175115#175115)