# How do I install BCM43142 wireless drivers for Dell Vostro 3460/3560?

Tags: wireless, dell-vostro

I have a Dell Vostro 3460 with one of the new Broadcom 43142 hybrid Wireless/Bluetooth chips. Neither the proprietary driver (`wl`) nor the `b43` driver supports this.

`lspci -nn` gives me

```
01:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation Device [14e4:4365] (rev 01)
02:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Atheros Communications Inc. AR8161 Gigabit Ethernet [1969:1091] (rev 10)
```

I manage to install `1969:1091` with *compat-wireless' alx*, but could not find any alternative for this *Broadcom  4365*...

Do you guys know any driver for this controller? I am seriously considering to buy a compatible USB card?

Comment: **^^^not a duplicate, because** no current public driver, i.e. `wl`, `b43`, etc. supports this new chipset.

Comment: For 13.04, this works - http://askubuntu.com/questions/289609/dell-3721-wifi-problem-ubuntu-13-04/289614#289614

Comment: Solution for **14.10** (64-bit) or **15.04** (64-bit) here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/553615/cant-enable-the-proprietary-drivers-for-broadcom-bcm43142-wireless-after-instal

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### 12.04

Drivers for this are only officially available *with* the Vostro 3460 as provided by Dell.

However, [based on the instructions and the Dell deb from the Vostro 3560 provided in this forum thread](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=145884), I have created a modified DEB file that compiles and installs the driver on *12.04* (see thread for 11.10 link).

First, install the prerequisites by opening a terminal and pasting, one line at a time:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers$(uname -r | grep -Po "\-[a-z].*")
sudo apt-get install build-essential dkms
```

Please download the appropriate DEB file from Dropbox here:

- [**32-bit/i386**](https://www.dropbox.com/s/n76dcsdtayvp0wm/wireless-bcm43142-dkms-6.20.55.19_i386.deb)
- [**64-bit/amd64**](https://www.dropbox.com/s/jerkl6uqal5ylv3/wireless-bcm43142-dkms-6.20.55.19_amd64.deb)

Open a terminal, and install it with `sudo dpkg -i`.

Hopefully it works!

Edit: 12.04 now has an updated `bcmwl-kernel-source` package that reportedly supports BCM43142. [bug#923809, comment 15](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/bcmwl/+bug/923809/comments/15)

Comment: Thanks for replying @izy. Is there any alternative driver for 12.04/10 **32 bit**?

Comment: The linked file *should* compile on 32-bit. Doesn't it?

Comment: I get a `dpkg` error: `package architecture (amd64) does not match system (i386)`

Comment: @rodrigo: please see edited answer, download the 32-bit package and you should be good to go.

Comment: sorry for the delay to get back on this, and thanks for providing the 32-bit version. I tried with both Ubuntu 11.10 and 12.10, but got similar _dpkg_ errors: `.../build/src/wl/sys/wl_linux.c:50:24: fatal error: asm/system.h: N
compilation terminated`. Am I missing anything?

Comment: @rodrigo: You seem to be missing the linux headers. Please install them with `sudo apt-get install linux-headers$(uname -r | grep -Po "\-[a-z].*")` and then try again.

Comment: I have the headers. Will try with Ubuntu 12.04 32/64-bit later on today.

Comment: I installed 32-bit/i386 on 12.04 but the wireless network selection was not activated. I still have Bluetooth and Wired connection only. Is there anything that should be installed with this driver?

Comment: I was finally able to test this driver with a 3.2.0-30-generic x86_64. It was successfully installed. Thanks again.

Comment: When upgrading to quantal (12.10) I got an error about the wireless-bcm43142-oneiric-dkms. Apparently it has something to do with the kernel: http://askubuntu.com/a/195598/22147. Would it be possible to update this answer to also include 12.10?

Comment: Thanks izx. I got the package installed successfully, but still i am not able to start the wireless card

Comment: For Ubuntu 12.04 I found this page: http://www.ubuntu.com/certification/hardware/201202-10527/ meaning, there is a certified release now.

Answer (score 11):

### 12.10

Please verify your pci.id with a terminal command:

```
    lspci -nn
```

Is it 14e4:4365? I am not sure it is even possible in a 32-bit system. If you have a 64-bit system and the device I mentioned, then I suggest this package: http://jas.gemnetworks.com/debian/pool/main/w/wireless-bcm43142/wireless-bcm43142-dkms_6.20.55.19-1_amd64.deb

First install the prerequisites:

```
    sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic build-essential dkms
```

Then install the package with:

```
    cd Desktop   <--or wherever you downloaded the deb
    sudo dpkg -i wire*.deb
    sudo modprobe wl
```

Comment: This solution worked with Ubuntu 12.10 64-bit

Answer (score 1):

I tried following method to install Broadcom wireless Driver with Dell Vostro 3500  in Ubuntu/Xubuntu 12.04 (64 bit) Linux.

First of all check your wireless chipset model number,

```
lspci | grep Network
```

Install following prerequisites,

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic build-essential dkms
```

Download following package and install,

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6E3iEzJp74uSGZjVDF2YnM5eFE/view

Open the following file:

```
gedit /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
```

Add the following lines:

```
blacklist b43
blacklist b43legacy
blacklist bcma
blacklist ndiswrapper
```

Comment the following line,

```
# blacklist bcm43xx
```

Restart your laptop and check whether the wireless is working or not.