# Broadcom 4365 wireless driver with 3.4 / 3.5 kernel

Tags: wireless, drivers, kernel, broadcom

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to Install Broadcom / STA Wireless card (BCM43XX)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/how-to-install-broadcom-sta-wireless-card-bcm43xx)

I used this [package](https://www.dropbox.com/s/jerkl6uqal5ylv3/wireless-bcm43142-dkms-6.20.55.19_amd64.deb) to install the driver on 3.2 Kernel and it was working perfectly.

Unfortunately the system used to freeze randomly with 3.2 kernel so I installed 3.4 kernel, now there is no freezing, the only problem is that my wifi card is not working, I tried to re-install the package, but didn't work.

I can see the driver in the "additional drivers" and it say that it is active, but when I execute `iwconfig` it doesn't show up. I've even tried `ndiswraper` and that didn't work either.

my `lspci`:

```
01:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation Device 4365 (rev 01)
```

Answer (score 6):

Updated, some additional fixes, and kernels 3.6.x now also supported

http://jas.gemnetworks.com/debian/pool/main/w/wireless-bcm43142/wireless-bcm43142-dkms_6.20.55.19-1_amd64.deb

You may also want to look at notes and changelog here:

http://jas.gemnetworks.com/wireless-bcm43142/

If you have problem loading this module under stock Ubuntu 12.04 kernel 3.2.x there might be problem with installed backported modules. In my case it's linux-backports-modules-cw-3.4-3.2.0-* containing cfg80211 and lib80211 modules which conficts with stock kernel ones. I need this package because it contains alx driver for my ethernet network adapter.
If you try to `modprobe wl` it tends to load dependencies from backported cfg80211 and lib80211 drivers and fails to load with
    FATAL: Error inserting wl (/lib/modules/3.2.0-34-generic/updates/dkms/wl.ko): Invalid argument

I've solved it by creating modprobe configuration /etc/modprobe.d/wl.conf which forces loading of stock kernel modules

```
install cfg80211 /sbin/insmod /lib/modules/`/bin/uname -r`/kernel/net/wireless/cfg80211.ko
install lib80211 /sbin/insmod /lib/modules/`/bin/uname -r`/kernel/net/wireless/lib80211.ko
```

Comment: Hey Jasmine, thanks for the work. I installed the driver, and it does appear in the 'additional drivers' section in Software Sources, but the applet doesn't show a wireless section, 'iwconfig' gives 'no wireless extensions.' and 'lshw' gives '*-network UNCLAIMED' for my wireless :( any clue?

Comment: I believe you need to reboot after first install. Then, make sure wl module is loaded

lsmod | grep ^wl

ifconfig -a

you should see a new "ethX" interface

The next update I'm working on renames the ethX to wlanX
Currently working on fix for 3.6 kernel as well.

Comment: hmm. I'm fearing there's something fundamentally wrong my system. 'lsmod | grep ^wl ifconfig -a' gives 'grep: ifconfig: No such file or directory', sudo makes no difference. (I rebooted several times in the meantime)

Comment: Sorry. Everything got wrapped. no matter what I do, lines get wrapped in comments.
  
    `lsmod | grep ^wl`  

    If the above command returns nothing, then wl module isn't loaded. Which is weird, because it should be automatically loaded. Regardless, to load the module if it wasn't already loaded:  
  
    `sudo modprobe wl`  

    Now, you should have a new ethX interface (in the next update, this is renamed to wlanX)  
  
    `/sbin/ifconfig -a`  
  and  
    `/sbin/iwconfig`  

    N.B.: please wait for coming, cleaner, update. And 3.6 kernel is supported ;)

Comment: *sigh*. I get `FATAL: Module wl not found.` Should I follow these instructions: http://wiki.debian.org/wl? (if so: squeeze or wheezy?)

Comment: edited answer to reflect updated release. hope it works for you.

Comment: wohoo. The updated installation works! :) Thanks so much!

Comment: glad to be of help :)

Comment: Hey, I used you updated link for the installation, but I am still getting a `FATAL: Module wl not found` and the driver seems not to be running. I am working with a 3.5.* - kernel. Apt-get tells me that `wireless-bcm43142-dkms is already the newest version`.

Comment: Solved. Updated kernel to 3.5.0-21-generic and reinstalled the headers. Not sure what it was that helped finally, but after reinstalling your .deb I am now online :) I tried to `sudo apt-get install wireless-bcm43142-dkms`, but it says its already the newest version. Does that mean I will be notfied for updates?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem after upgrading to kernel 3.5.0 and found the solution in the following thread: http://www.spinics.net/lists/linux-wireless/msg97247.html

After installing the mentioned package (http://jas.gemnetworks.com/debian/wireless-bcm43142-dkms-6.20.55.19_amd64.deb) the wireless started working again.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.