# Unable to enable wireless on a Vostro 2520

Tags: 12.04, wireless, dell, atheros

I have a Vostro 2520 and not sure how to enable wireless on my machine. The details are given below, would appreciate any pointers to resolving this issue.

`lsmod` returns

```
Module                  Size  Used by ath9k                 132390  0 
ath9k_common           14053  1 ath9k ath9k_hw              411151  2
ath9k,ath9k_common ath                    24067  3
ath9k,ath9k_common,ath9k_hw b43                   365785  0  mac80211 
506816  2 ath9k,b43 cfg80211              205544  4
ath9k,ath,b43,mac80211 bcma                   26696  1 b43 ssb        
52752  1 b43 ndiswrapper           282628  0  ums_realtek           
18248  0  usb_storage            49198  1 ums_realtek uas             
18180  0  snd_hda_codec_hdmi     32474  1  snd_hda_codec_cirrus   
24002  1  joydev                 17693  0  parport_pc            
32866  0  ppdev                  17113  0  rfcomm                
47604  0  bnep                   18281  2  bluetooth            
180104  10 rfcomm,bnep psmouse                97362  0  dell_wmi      
12681  0  sparse_keymap          13890  1 dell_wmi snd_hda_intel      
33773  3  snd_hda_codec         127706  3
snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_cirrus,snd_hda_intel snd_hwdep       
13668  1 snd_hda_codec snd_pcm                97188  3
snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec snd_seq_midi          
13324  0  snd_rawmidi            30748  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_seq_midi_event     14899  1 snd_seq_midi snd_seq               
61896  2 snd_seq_midi,snd_seq_midi_event snd_timer              29990 
2 snd_pcm,snd_seq snd_seq_device         14540  3
snd_seq_midi,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq wmi                    19256  1
dell_wmi snd                    78855  16
snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_cirrus,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hwdep,snd_pcm,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq,snd_timer,snd_seq_device
mac_hid                13253  0  i915                  473240  3 
drm_kms_helper         46978  1 i915 uvcvideo               72627  0 
drm                   242038  4 i915,drm_kms_helper videodev          
98259  1 uvcvideo soundcore              15091  1 snd dell_laptop     
18119  0  dcdbas                 14490  1 dell_laptop i2c_algo_bit    
13423  1 i915 v4l2_compat_ioctl32    17128  1 videodev snd_page_alloc 
18529  2 snd_hda_intel,snd_pcm video                  19596  1 i915
serio_raw              13211  0  mei                    41616  0  lp  
17799  0  parport                46562  3 parport_pc,ppdev,lp r8169   
62099  0
```

`sudo lshw -class network`

```
  *-network UNCLAIMED     
       description: Network controller
       product: Broadcom Corporation
       vendor: Broadcom Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:07:00.0
       version: 01
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:f7c00000-f7c07fff   *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168B PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:09:00.0
       logical name: eth0
       version: 07
       serial: 78:45:c4:a3:aa:65
       size: 100Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd
autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=full firmware=rtl8168e-3_0.0.4
03/27/12 ip=192.168.1.5 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII
speed=100Mbit/s
       resources: irq:41 ioport:e000(size=256) memory:f0004000-f0004fff memory:f0000000-f0003fff
```

`rfkill list all`

```
0: dell-wifi: Wireless LAN  Soft blocked: yes   Hard blocked: yes 1:
dell-bluetooth: Bluetooth   Soft blocked: yes   Hard blocked: yes
```

Output of `lspci`:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Ivy Bridge DRAM Controller (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Ivy Bridge Graphics Controller (rev 09)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Panther Point MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Panther Point USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Panther Point High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Panther Point PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev c4)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Panther Point PCI Express Root Port 4 (rev c4)
00:1c.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Panther Point PCI Express Root Port 6 (rev c4)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Panther Point USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Panther Point LPC Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Panther Point 6 port SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 04)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation Panther Point SMBus Controller (rev 04)
07:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation Device 4365 (rev 01)
09:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168B PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet controller (rev 07)
```

Output of `lspci -v`:

```
0:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Ivy Bridge DRAM Controller (rev 09)
    Subsystem: Dell Device 0558
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: agpgart-intel

00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Ivy Bridge Graphics Controller (rev 09) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: Dell Device 0558
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 43
    Memory at f7800000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4M]
    Memory at e0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    I/O ports at f000 [size=64]
    Expansion ROM at <unassigned> [disabled]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: i915
    Kernel modules: i915

00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Panther Point MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Dell Device 0558
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 42
    Memory at f7d0a000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: mei
    Kernel modules: mei

00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Panther Point USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 (rev 04) (prog-if 20 [EHCI])
    Subsystem: Dell Device 0558
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 16
    Memory at f7d08000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: ehci_hcd

00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Panther Point High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Dell Device 0558
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 44
    Memory at f7d00000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd-hda-intel

00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Panther Point PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev c4) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=04, subordinate=04, sec-latency=0
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp

00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Panther Point PCI Express Root Port 4 (rev c4) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=07, subordinate=07, sec-latency=0
    Memory behind bridge: f7c00000-f7cfffff
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp

00:1c.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Panther Point PCI Express Root Port 6 (rev c4) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=09, subordinate=09, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: 0000e000-0000efff
    Prefetchable memory behind bridge: 00000000f0000000-00000000f00fffff
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp

00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Panther Point USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 (rev 04) (prog-if 20 [EHCI])
    Subsystem: Dell Device 0558
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 23
    Memory at f7d07000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: ehci_hcd

00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Panther Point LPC Controller (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Dell Device 0558
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel modules: iTCO_wdt

00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Panther Point 6 port SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 04) (prog-if 01 [AHCI 1.0])
    Subsystem: Dell Device 0558
    Flags: bus master, 66MHz, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 40
    I/O ports at f0b0 [size=8]
    I/O ports at f0a0 [size=4]
    I/O ports at f090 [size=8]
    I/O ports at f080 [size=4]
    I/O ports at f060 [size=32]
    Memory at f7d06000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=2K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: ahci

00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation Panther Point SMBus Controller (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Dell Device 0558
    Flags: medium devsel, IRQ 11
    Memory at f7d05000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256]
    I/O ports at f040 [size=32]
    Kernel modules: i2c-i801

07:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation Device 4365 (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Dell Device 0016
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 10
    Memory at f7c00000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=32K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>

09:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168B PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet controller (rev 07)
    Subsystem: Dell Device 0558
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 41
    I/O ports at e000 [size=256]
    Memory at f0004000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Memory at f0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: r8169
    Kernel modules: r8169
```

Comment: @Joe - your rfkill results say you have a hard-lock - this means there is a physical switch (keyboard Fn type switch, bios, or slider switch) that is turned off.  Can you check this please and report back?

Comment: I did some googling on your wifi card, the Broadcom 4365. I found this answer, maybe it will offer some hints:
http://askubuntu.com/questions/178352/broadcom-4365-wireless-driver-with-3-4-3-5-kernel
Good luck, - R.R.G

Comment: To enable wireless, I went to System Settings > Network > Wireless and turned it ON. But this is on 12.04.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Installing Broadcom Wireless Drivers](http://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers)

Answer (score 0):

Edit the file `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf` and in the end type :

```
blacklist acer_wmi
```

Reboot and you’re done. If you’re doing it entirely from the GUI, then editing the file could be done by pressing <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> (this would open a “Run” window) and typing there `gksu gedit /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf` then add this line below

```
rmmod dell_laptop
```

Comment: I am not using acer, should I still blacklist it

Comment: I use lenovo laptop, and blacklist acer_wmi. The first time I install ubuntu hardy, it works, the second time I install, it doesn't work. I think you should try it, if it doesn't work, let remove it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-installer
sudo apt-get remove bcmwl-kernel-source
```

It worked for me on a Dell Inspiron 6400 with the Broadcom wifi chip.

Comment: How do I know what chip am using right now

Comment: Processing triggers for man-db ...
Setting up b43-fwcutter (1:015-9) ...
Setting up firmware-b43-installer (1:015-9) ...
No chroot environment found. Starting normal installation

Comment: I tried pressing Fn+F2 after this, but it doesn't seem to have any effect.

Comment: To learn what chip is installed on your pc type lspci in a terminal and look for the wireless lan line.

Comment: I don't see anything for the wireless lan line, I have modified the question with lspci output

Comment: Broadcom Corporation Device 4365 (rev 01) is your Wifi card.

Comment: I don't know if this might help: http://askubuntu.com/questions/175104/how-do-i-install-bcm43142-wireless-drivers-for-dell-vostro-3460-3560

Answer (score 0):

Open terminal.  Just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command below.

```
sudo rfkill unblock all
```

Comment: doesn't seem to have any effect on the output.

Comment: list the output of sudo iwconfig