# How to get my Broadcom 4365 WiFi adapter working?

Tags: wireless, drivers, broadcom

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to Install Broadcom / STA Wireless card (BCM43XX)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/how-to-install-broadcom-sta-wireless-card-bcm43xx)

My [previous question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/226967/dell-inspiron-n4050-no-wireless) about this issue had been closed, and I had been directed to [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/how-to-install-broadcom-sta-wireless-card-bcm43xx). I read through it all day, but none of the solutions over there helped. I still can't even switch the wireless adapter on. The only working wireless module is Bluetooth. I know for a fact that the wireless adapter is not faulty, because after having asked this question, I installed Windows and it worked flawlessly. I just decided to give Ubuntu another shot.

Here's the story: on my Dell Inspiron N4050, I upgraded from the preinstalled 10.10 to 11.04 then 11.10. Then I installed the proprietary driver through Additional Drivers. Since then, the wireless card just stopped working completely, and won't even switch on. Not even a clean, fresh installation of 12.04 fixed it.

So what now? Should I take it in for warranty replacement?

Here's the relevant output of `lspci`:

```
09:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation Device 4365 (rev 01)
```

Comment: Start by typing `lspci` in a terminal, identify your wireless card and edit your question with this information.

Comment: Please post the output of `sudo rfkill list`.

Comment: The answer by jasmine.aura to this question (http://askubuntu.com/questions/178352/broadcom-4365-wireless-driver-with-3-4-3-5-kernel) may help.

Answer (score 0):

What's your kernel version?

Type: `uname -r`. If it's 3.2 something try to install this [package](https://www.dropbox.com/s/jerkl6uqal5ylv3/wireless-bcm43142-dkms-6.20.55.19_amd64.deb).

If it's not 3.2 or it doesn't work, [please take a look at this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/178352/broadcom-4365-wireless-driver-with-3-4-3-5-kernel).

To do things the safe way , [here's the package author site](http://jas.gemnetworks.com/wireless-bcm43142/), among with it's source and compiled deb.

Comment: Please clarify why to link to an external `.deb` file on a Dropbox location. Sounds suspicious to me.

Comment: It was linked in the other question, the second link i posted. They said the wifi worked with this package.

Comment: Use common sense. Don't install random packages from untrusted sources.

Comment: I did a search here on askubuntu, and that solution showed up. I didn't thought of security risks. Thanks for the warning! Added a link with the source of the deb file.