# Broadcom wireless 43142 conflict Atheros 8161 in kernel 3.5 (Ubuntu 12.10)

Tags: wireless, drivers, kernel, broadcom

I am exactly in the situation of [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/178352/broadcom-4365-wireless-driver-with-3-4-3-5-kernel). However, my wireless card is a different model: I have a dell vostro 3460 with an Atheros AR8161 Ethernet card and a Broadcom 43142 wireless card. I previously installed Ubuntu 12.04 and having only the wireless card work, but no way to have the ethernet card work. Now, I've just upgrade to Ubuntu 12.10 hoping having both cards work (and also because it randomly frozen), but I am only able to make the ethernet card work (using linux-backports-modules).

For the wireless card, I am exactly in the situation of [this reply](https://askubuntu.com/a/203082/117629): After installing the wireless-bcm43142-dkms_6.20.55.19-1_amd64.deb, when doing `modprobe wl`, I had the following error:

```
FATAL: Error inserting wl (/lib/modules/3.5.0-18-generic/updates/dkms/wl.ko): Invalid argument
```

As Jasmine mentioned in his post, there can be conflict among stuffs for ethernet card and the ones for wireless card. Thus, I try his commands:

```
install cfg80211 /sbin/insmod /lib/modules/`/bin/uname -r`/kernel/net/wireless/cfg80211.ko
```

But I got the following error:

```
install: target `/lib/modules/3.5.0-18-generic/kernel/net/wireless/cfg80211.ko' is not a directory
```

I Think the difference is that his kernel is 3.2 and mine is 3.5. But I have no idea how to make it work

Comment: Just to make sure, did you make sure that the 3.5.0-18... directory exists. Since it is mentioning that the directory/file does not exist in that line.

Comment: The `/lib/modules/3.5.0-18-generic/kernel/net/wireless/cfg80211.ko` does exist but it is a file, with permission `-rw-r--r-- 1 root root`, not a directory

Answer (score 0):

You could try to disable driver for your wireless card in Settings -> Source Software -> additional drivers (sorry if the path is not correct, i have Ubuntu in italian) and then restart. For me it worked.