# No wireless drivers installed? how do i install them?

Tags: 12.04, wireless, networking

apparently when I installed 12.04 I was not online and no wireless drivers were installed - if I connect a cable I do get internet access.
this is a b590 lenovo laptop.

when I type in `lspci` I get this:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family DRAM Controller (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Panther Point USB xHCI Host Controller (rev 04)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Panther Point MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Panther Point USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Panther Point High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Panther Point PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev c4)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Panther Point PCI Express Root Port 2 (rev c4)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Panther Point PCI Express Root Port 4 (rev c4)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Panther Point USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Panther Point LPC Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Panther Point 6 port SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 04)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation Panther Point SMBus Controller (rev 04)
02:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation Device 4365 (rev 01)
03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168B PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet controller (rev 07)
```

In case that helps at all

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/178352/broadcom-4365-wireless-driver-with-3-4-3-5-kernel

https://encrypted.google.com/search?q=Broadcom+Corporation+Device+4365+linux

Comment: what is network controller then??

Comment: i see now that this line:

`02:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation Device 4365 (rev 01)`

is the controller, ill follow what Samuel posted - thank you

Comment: well for some reason i cant run sudo m-a, as said in a few guides here... trying to find a solution for that now

Answer (score 0):

Try navigating to:

> System Settings > Software & Updates

Then click on the aditional drivers tab to see if any proprietary drivers are displayed. If they are you can enable them which should hopefully solve your wireless issues. You may need to be connected to your router via an ethernet cable though, in order to download the driver.

Comment: yaiks, i tried that and it found the broadcom one, but after giving my users password i got a black screen with tons of line ending with "Bad RIP" and had to reboot - after the reboot I DO have wireless drivers and it works.. but why did i get that black screen of death?\

Comment: I have no idea why it would do that! Perhaps that could be another question to raise? It will be interesting to see whether it does it again!

Comment: well anyway for now the drivers works and i have wireless access.. oddly enough first time i went to additional drivers there were non.. anyway thanks to everyone that helped!