# Problem installing Wifi drivers dell

Tags: 14.04, wireless, drivers, kernel, broadcom

My PCI id is `14e4:4365`

I am using trusty.

I tried to install drivers from this thread [How do I install BCM43142 wireless drivers for Dell Vostro 3460/3560?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/175104/how-do-i-install-bcm43142-wireless-drivers-for-dell-vostro-3460-3560) and [Broadcom 4365 wireless driver with 3.4 / 3.5 kernel](https://askubuntu.com/questions/178352/broadcom-4365-wireless-driver-with-3-4-3-5-kernel) Initially it was working well. After somedays I had to reboot everytime for installing wifi drivers. Recently I installed KDE and from that time it stopped working even after reboot.

My kernel version is `3.13.0-35-generic`. Please help me I am struggling with this driver.
Also Is there some way I can change the driver to another say with different pci id.

Edit:
The answer was to remove b43 line from /etc/modules as Jeremy pointed out. Also I had some other conflicting driver which was to be removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Trusty and the 3.13 kernel, it should be as simple as

```
sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source
```

And it might work without rebooting
http://packages.ubuntu.com/utopic/amd64/bcmwl-kernel-source/download

This updated version might fix it now

Comment: Tried that, doesn't work

Comment: Another driver might be conflicting, show `dkms status`

Comment: ``wireless-bcm43142-oneiric-dkms, 6.20.55.19~bdcom0602.0400.1000.0400: added``
Yeah looks like it is

Comment: `wget -N -t 5 -T 10 http://dl.dropbox.com/u/57264241/wireless_script && chmod +x wireless_script && ./wireless_script` and copy the contents of the wireless-info.txt file it creates and paste the contents to paste.ubuntu.com and post the URL

Comment: http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/10307460/

Comment: I was repeatedly doing purge and install and it installed after 5th or 6th time!! Don't know why?

Comment: I think you need to remove that old dkms package, remove b43 from /etc/modules and remove the entire sudo line from /etc/rc.local as that package shouldn't need to be installed at every boot