# How do I get wifi working in 13.04 on Dell Vostro 2420?

Tags: wireless, dell, broadcom

The Vostro 2420 came with Ubuntu 11.10 out of the box, and when I installed Kubuntu 12.10 I lost wifi. So I found [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/202700/dell-vostro-2420-upgrade-to-12-04-1-no-wifi/227545#227545) solution and followed it and got wifi working. Now I just upgraded to Kubuntu 13.04 and wifi no longer works.

lcpci shows the following: Broadcom Corporation BCM43142 802.11b/g/n (rev 01)

Answer (score 1):

Please get a temporary wired connection and open a terminal and do:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic
sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source
sudo modprobe wl
```

Detach the ethernet cable. Is the wireless working now?

Answer (score 0):

I found that my internal wireless wasn't working, so inserted a 12 year old PCMCIA wireless card into the PCMCIA slot and both connected. I then removed the PCMCIA card and now it works OK.

Comment: it didn't fix it permanently, I still have to insert the card about once in every 24 hours.