# Vostro 3560 Wireless on Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: wireless, drivers, dell, 12.10

I have been using Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS on a Dell Vostro 3560 for some time now. At first I had issues with the wireless but I was pointed to a driver from Ubuntu 11.xx for a Broadcom BCM43142 and that did work! however with the upgrade to 12.10 I find myself at a lost because the driver will not work anymore. When trying to reinstall it I get "Driver of bad quality" I still install it but it just wont work.

I cant seem to find anything on this issue for 12.10 and didn't know if anyone had any advice or if someone could point me in the right direction on resources to write my own driver for it. As I know C/C++ but have never written a driver for a Linux machine before.

Thanks for any help!

To be more clear

I installed Ubuntu 12.10 Desktop on my Dell Vostro 3560 laptop. When I log in, my wireless card isn't visible in the Network Manager popup menu, although the wired network shows up there. I installed the driver mentioned below and that did help me on 12.04 but is now broken due to "Poor quality"

a sudo lspci -nn command brings up:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge [0600]: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor DRAM Controller 
[8086:0154] (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller [8086:0166] (rev 09)
00:14.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI Host Controller [8086:1e31] (rev 04)
00:16.0 Communication controller [0780]: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 [8086:1e3a] (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 [8086:1e2d] (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller [8086:1e20] (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1 [8086:1e10] (rev c4)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 2 [8086:1e12] (rev c4)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 3 [8086:1e14] (rev c4)
00:1d.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 [8086:1e26] (rev 04)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge [0601]: Intel Corporation HM77 Express Chipset LPC Controller [8086:1e57] (rev 04)
00:1f.2 SATA controller [0106]: Intel Corporation 7 Series Chipset Family 6-port SATA Controller [AHCI mode] [8086:1e03] (rev 04)
00:1f.3 SMBus [0c05]: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller [8086:1e22] (rev 04)
01:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168B PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet controller [10ec:8168] (rev 07)
**02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [14e4:4365] (rev 01)**
```

Comment: We need more hardware information to help you, can you look at [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/14008/i-have-a-hardware-detection-problem-what-logs-do-i-need-to-look-into) and then edit your question adding the information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've prepared a deb based on [How do I install BCM43142 wireless drivers for Dell Vostro 3460/3560?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/175104/how-do-i-install-bcm43142-wireless-drivers-for-dell-vostro-3460-3560)
for ubuntu 12.10 amd64. Tested. Wifi+BT are working for me.

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/27868405/wireless-bcm43142-dkms-6.20.55.19_quantal_amd64.deb

Comment: That was the driver I was using for 12.04.1 however now with 12.10 I get a "Package of bad quality" warning, I still install but it wont work. It goes on to say that the package doesn't meet quality standards.

Comment: This must have worked, I have restarted my computer about 3-5 times and it just started working randomly. The only other thing I did before this last restart was installed Apache, PHP5, and MySQL but I dont see how this would have made any difference.

So my advice to anyone with this issue install the driver listed above and you may need to restart your computer a bunch of times to get it to start working.

Comment: The driver is really of bad quality, it isn't packaged properly. The source is a little modified to build on ubuntu 12.10 kernel and the version of the package should be bumped, but I lack knowledge how to do it all the right way.

Comment: @ngille et al, "bad quality" just means that the packaging doesn't follow the Ubuntu packaging specification.  The quality of the components is independent of the packaging.

Answer (score 2):

i tried all the possible solutions including ndiswrapper (using win7 driver) but none worked.
--> finally - I succeeded activating the wireless using Ubuntu 12.10 on Dell Vostro 3560 using only this solution !! follow the instructions on this link:
http://forums.fedoraforum.org/archive/index.php/t-283824.html 
(update to the instructions: use apt-get instead of yum)