# Wireless Driver for ubuntu 12.10 32 bit on Dell inspiron 5520

Tags: wireless

I have installed ubuntu 12.10 lately and I tried to install the wireless Driver by seeing various sites and threads.
I have installed a deb from here :
[How do I install BCM43142 wireless drivers for Dell Vostro 3460/3560?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/175104/how-do-i-install-bcm43142-wireless-drivers-for-dell-vostro-3460-3560)

But it doesn't have any effect on my system.
I additional driver section I get 
    Using Broadcom 802.11 Linux STA wireless drivers source frm wireless-bcm43142-oneiric-          dkms(opensource)

But It also shows : This device is using an alternate driver.

I have these results:

```
sudo lshw -class network

*-network
   description: Ethernet interface
   product: RTL8101E/RTL8102E PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller
   vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:07:00.0
   logical name: eth0
   version: 05
   serial: d4:be:d9:2d:d3:86
   size: 10Mbit/s
   capacity: 100Mbit/s
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp      mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
   configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-   NAPI duplex=half firmware=rtl_nic/rtl8105e-1.fw latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII    speed=10Mbit/s
   resources: irq:43 ioport:2000(size=256) memory:c1404000-c1404fff memory:c1400000-    c1403fff
*-network UNCLAIMED
   description: Network controller
   product: BCM43142 802.11b/g/n
   vendor: Broadcom Corporation
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:08:00.0
   version: 01
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
   configuration: latency=0
   resources: memory:c1500000-c1507fff
```

And 
    lspci -vvv

```
08:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM43142 802.11b/g/n (rev 01)
Subsystem: Dell Wireless 1704 802.11n + BT 4.0
Control: I/O- Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping-   SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort-     >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
Latency: 0, Cache Line Size: 64 bytes
Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 11
Region 0: Memory at c1500000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=32K]
Capabilities: <access denied>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the 64bit ubuntu version and here is a 64bit driver for your wireless http://jas.gemnetworks.com/debian/pool/main/w/wireless-bcm43142/wireless-bcm43142-dkms_6.20.55.19-1_amd64.deb