# Dell Vostro 3560 Wireless occurs error while installing

Tags: wireless

I saw:
[dropbox driver](https://askubuntu.com/questions/175104/how-do-i-install-bcm43142-wireless-drivers-for-dell-vostro-3460-3560)

And had the same issue, that is not solved in that topic:

I tried with both Ubuntu 11.10 and 12.10, but got similar dpkg errors: `.../build/src/wl/sys/wl_linux.c:50:24: fatal error: asm/system.h: N compilation terminated.`

Am I missing anything?

Is driver for i386 bad and i must install x64 ubuntu, or what?

Answer (score 0):

The i386 driver, even with some modifications, errors out for me. On the other hand, I've installed it without problems on 64-bit in 12.04 and 12.10.