# Dell Inspiron 5720 Wifi (Broadcom BCM43142, Ubuntu 12.10)

Tags: wireless, 12.10, dell, broadcom

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I install BCM43142 wireless drivers for Dell Vostro 3460/3560?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/175104/how-do-i-install-bcm43142-wireless-drivers-for-dell-vostro-3460-3560)

I've installed Ubuntu 12.10 on Dell Inspiron 5720. Cant get wifi to work.
**sudo lshw -C network:**

> *-network UNCLAIMED
>          description: Network controller
>          product: BCM43142 802.11b/g/n
>          vendor: Broadcom Corporation
>          physical id: 0
>          bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
>          version: 01
>          width: 64 bits
>          clock: 33MHz
>          capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
>          configuration: latency=0
>          resources: memory:f1500000-f1507fff

Installing *b43-fwcutter/firmware-b43legacy-installer* never gave any results. On b43 and b43 legacy website ( http://wireless.kernel.org/en/users/Drivers/b43) it's said that **BCM4313** is NOT there and NOT supported.

I've also tried *kernel-remove-source* and *kernel-install-source* and same command for *headers*, but got no results.

How can I fix it? Help me please, thanks!