# Dell Vostro 3560 WIFI installation kernel problem

Tags: wireless, dell

I used this command for this [AU Q&A](https://askubuntu.com/questions/175104/how-do-i-install-bcm43142-wireless-drivers-for-dell-vostro-3460-3560)

```
sudo dpkg -i 1.deb
```

And I get this message:

> Module build for the currently running kernel was skipped since the
>   kernel source for this kernel does not seem to be installed.

I do have this installed but still don't have a working WiFi

Is it a problem in my kernel maybe? fresh Ubuntu 12.10 x64, and I have tried x32

Comment: Your kernel is different from what it was with 12.04. You need to search for new drivers. But can't you get the drivers using `Addtional drivers`? or you can follow this http://askubuntu.com/a/215923/35775

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dell Inspiron 5720 Wifi (Broadcom BCM43142, Ubuntu 12.10)](http://askubuntu.com/questions/215890/dell-inspiron-5720-wifi-broadcom-bcm43142-ubuntu-12-10) .. tryout the answer since the answer is accepted and question is for 12.10

Comment: i have broadcom wireless 14e4:4365 from lspci -nn, but after installing drivers and reboot im getting "Module wl not Found" from sudo modprobe wl

Comment: did you first undo what ever you did earlier?

Answer (score 0):

Your message suggests the linux-headers-generic are not installed or not correctly. Please do:

```
    sudo apt-get install --reinstall linux-headers-generic linux-headers-`uname -r` build-essential dkms
    sudo dpkg -P 1.deb
    sudo dpkg -i 1.deb
    sudo modprobe wl
```

The backticks are on the left side of my US keyboard on the same key with ~.