# ubuntu can't connect to wireless

Tags: wireless, networking, drivers

I installed ubuntu 12.04 on my dell inspiron 5720 and I can't connect to any wireless networks, at the right top, it doesn't show any networks.

I tried both the 32bit and 64bit versions, I reinstalled my os several times, I googled a lot, and none of it seems to work. My pc is dual boot with windows 7, and the wireless is working fine there so my network card is allright

I searched for additional drivers in system settings and it can't find anything
then I went to the software-center to install of the broadcom stuff but still no wireless

the output of

```
lspci -vvnn | grep 14e4
```

is

```
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation Device [14e4:4365] (rev 01)
```

it doesn't even show wlan

Answer (score 0):

Please see here. You have the same device and need the same fix, including a 64-bit installation:  [Dell Inspiron 5720 Wifi (Broadcom BCM43142, Ubuntu 12.10)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/215890/dell-inspiron-5720-wifi-broadcom-bcm43142-ubuntu-12-10/215923#215923)

Comment: That didn't work, I get this error when I install the .deb package

dpkg: vereistenproblemen verhinderen de configuratie van wireless-bcm43142-dkms:
 wireless-bcm43142-dkms is afhankelijk van dkms (>= 2.1.0.0); maar:
  Pakket `dkms' is niet geïnstalleerd.
dpkg: fout bij afhandelen van wireless-bcm43142-dkms (--install):
 vereistenproblemen - blijft ongeconfigureerd
Fouten gevonden tijdens behandelen van:
 wireless-bcm43142-dkms

I hope you understand it, it's in dutch. If I trie to translate it, it says: error at dealing with -package name-
requirement problem - remains uncofigured

Comment: never mind, it worked now somehow! THANKS! If you weren't a guy, I'd kiss you