# How to get WiFi not working on Dell Inspiron 15R 5520 notebook?

Tags: wireless, dell, inspiron

Issuing `lspci -vnn` gave me this (relevant) output:

```
08:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM43142 802.11b/g/n
[14e4:4365] (rev 01)
```

I don't know how to proceed in order to get it working. Help on this is appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure it is BCM43142 and not BCM4312 ?

Comment: Please check here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/215890/dell-inspiron-5720-wifi-broadcom-bcm43142-ubuntu-12-10

Comment: i tried installing Broadcom Corporation BCM43142 from software center but dint fix at all

Answer (score 0):

```
$ lspci -vvnn | grep 14e4
08:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [14e4:4365] (rev 01)
```

download this file: http://jas.gemnetworks.com/debian/pool/main/w/wireless-bcm43142/wireless-bcm43142-dkms_6.20.55.19-1_amd64.deb

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic build-essential dkms
```

navigate to the folder you have saved the downloaded file and run this command.

```
sudo dpkg -i wireless-bcm43142-dkms_6.20.55.19-1_amd64.deb
```

i tried this but i was to fix : lo no extension

Comment: Please, edit your own question if you want to add more details.

Answer (score 0):

For my dell 5520 inspiron 15 R

1) connect to the internet via USB tethering with a smartphone.

2) Update with `sudo apt update`

3) Reboot

4) Find **Additional Drivers** and you will find wifi driver is not in use. Select Wireless Driver. (Only after full update of Ubuntu 14).

5) it will take 3 min to change settings, and your wifi will start working.

Answer (score -1):

This is how I solved the problem in my Dell Inspiron 5520 laptop. Once you have the *dkms* mentioned above you need to download and install BroAdcom STA. There are two ways of doing this

1. Search for Brodcom STA driver in http://pkgs.org and use `dpkg` command to install
2. The best way is to connect to ethernet and from your additional drivers list enable Brodcom STA wireless driver