# Wifi - wireless network not working after installing Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: wireless

I had installed ubuntu 12.04 in my Dell Vostro 3460. Initially wired as well wireless both are not working.

After installing `compat-wireless-2012-07-03-pc.tar.bz2` wired network fine but wireless is not working. Previously both were working fine with ubuntu 11.10. Also presently both network are working fine in Win7.

`lspci`:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Ivy Bridge DRAM Controller (rev 09)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Ivy Bridge PCI Express Root Port (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Ivy Bridge Graphics Controller (rev 09)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Panther Point USB xHCI Host Controller (rev 04)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Panther Point MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Panther Point USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Panther Point High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Panther Point PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev c4)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Panther Point PCI Express Root Port 5 (rev c4)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Panther Point USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Panther Point LPC Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Panther Point 6 port SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 04)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation Panther Point SMBus Controller (rev 04)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation Device 0de9 (rev a1)
02:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation Device 4365 (rev 01)
03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Atheros Communications Inc. AR8161 Gigabit Ethernet (rev 10)
```

`iwconfig`:

```
lo        no wireless extensions.
eth0      no wireless extensions.
```

`ifconfig`:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 84:8f:69:d4:35:9b  
          inet addr:10.24.22.72  Bcast:10.24.31.255  Mask:255.255.224.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::868f:69ff:fed4:359b/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:15332 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:10425 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:1
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:9262594 (9.2 MB)  TX bytes:1572030 (1.5 MB)
          Interrupt:16 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:1432 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1432 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:145656 (145.6 KB)  TX bytes:145656 (145.6 KB)
```

Comment: Please check here:  http://askubuntu.com/questions/215890/dell-inspiron-5720-wifi-broadcom-bcm43142-ubuntu-12-10

Answer (score 0):

I have a Vostro 1500 that I just set up recently and I had to do a bios update in order to get my wireless to work.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe wifi driver problem.

Try like this

First we have to remove the bcmwl kernel source:
    sudo apt-get remove bcmwl-kernel-source

Then again install :
    sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source

Answer (score 0):

Another reason for not detecting Wifi after new installations or such issues might be a problem with Wireless Network Adapter Drivers.

You can first check which Wifi Network Adapter is there in your PC.

```
lshw -C network
```

Mine Wireless N/W adapter was Realtek rtl8723be. So I installed the drivers from :

https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new

Thanks.