# Ubuntu 12.10 Dell/Broadcom BCM43142 driver install trouble

Tags: wireless

I am having trouble getting my Wireless to work on Ubuntu 12.10.  My laptop is a Dell 3520 and the wireless chipset is Broadcom BCM43142 pci.id [14e4:4365] rev 1.

The below question looks similar to my issue and I tried it but it didn't work:

[Dell Inspiron 5720 Wifi (Broadcom BCM43142, Ubuntu 12.10)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/215890/dell-inspiron-5720-wifi-broadcom-bcm43142-ubuntu-12-10/215923#215923)

When I try to `sudo dpkg -i wire*.deb` I get the below message:

> Module build for the currently running kernel was skipped since the
>   kernel source for this kernel does not seem to be installed.

When I grep for my installed headers using `dpkg --get-selections | grep headers` I see that I have:

```
linux-headers-3.5.0-17
linux-headers-3.5.0-21
linux-headers-3.5.0-21-generic
linux-headers-generic
```

Any idea what the issue is?

I checked if the wireless-bcm43142-dkms package got installed and it looks like it is when I do: `dpkg --get-selections | grep bcm`.

Answer (score 2):

Please try:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall linux-headers-`uname -r`
```

Those backticks are on the left side of my US keyboard on the same key with ~. After the headers for your currently running kernel are reinstalled, try again:

```
sudo dpkg -i wire*.deb
```

Answer (score -1):

please install the newest bcmwl-kernel-source:

http://launchpadlibrarian.net/128735877/bcmwl-kernel-source_6.20.155.1%2Bbdcom-0ubuntu0.0.1_amd64.deb