# Wireless not visible in Dell Vostro 2520, in Ubuntu 12.10?

Tags: 12.10, wireless, dell

I have executed the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-installer
sudo apt-get remove bcmwl-kernel-source
```

When I run `lspci`, I found "broadcom" as "bcm43142 chip".

I downloaded `wireless-bcm43142-dkms_6.20.55.19-1_amd64.deb` and attempted to install it with:

```
sudo dpkg -i wire*.deb
```

I am getting an error that b43 module does not exist in `/proc/modules` etc ...

What should I do?

Comment: You have a BCM43142, which is unsupported by b43. Please remove it. Possible duplicate of [Ubuntu 12.10 Dell/Broadcom BCM43142 driver install trouble](http://askubuntu.com/questions/231484/ubuntu-12-10-dell-broadcom-bcm43142-driver-install-trouble)

Comment: That's not really a significant error. The driver installation is trying to unload b43 yet can't find it in /proc/modules. In other words, it wants to unload a module (b43) that wasn't loaded in the first place. Please proceed with the next steps.