# Bluetooth isn't working in Dell Vostro 3560 with BCM43142 wireless adapter

Tags: wireless, 12.10, bluetooth, broadcom, dell-vostro

I installed the wireless driver using this instruction [How do I install BCM43142 wireless drivers for Dell Vostro 3460/3560](https://askubuntu.com/questions/175104/) and I have WiFi working. No problems here.

But unfortunately the bluetooth doesn't work. The Ubuntu bar shows the bluetooth sign and I can turn the bluetooth on/off but I can't discover any devices. And I can't find my laptop when I turn visibility On. So, obviously bluetooth doesn't work.

I couldn't find the reports that blutooth can actually work with this adapter in Ubuntu. So, is there anyone with BCM43142 adapter that have bluetooth working? I am using Ubuntu 12.10 x64.

Answer (score 1):

From [Revision #2](https://askubuntu.com/revisions/217590/2) of the question:

> After some fiddling around with different drivers from different sources I managed to get bluetooth working. Not flawlessly but at least I can pair a device.
>   Bluetooth started working after installation of this package [bt-bcm43142-onereic_0.0+20111116somerville2_amd64.deb](https://ikke.info/d//bt-bcm43142-onereic_0.0+20111116somerville2_amd64.deb).
>
> Originally I found this package on the disk with Ubuntu which came with the Laptop.
>   What this package does, it installs a firmware loader and a firmware itself. This firmware needs to get bluetooth working.
>
> Still bluetooth sometimes doesn't work even with this package. But manual loading the firmware helps.
>
> ```
> brcm_patchram_plus_usb --patchram /lib/firmware/BCM43142A0_001.001.011.0028.0036.hcd hci0
> ```
>
> Also I found it strange that this package writes all different ids into **/sys/bus/usb/drivers/btusb/new_id** because only one from the list matches my device ID
>
> Content of `bcm43142.conf`:
>
> ```
> install btusb /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install btusb && echo '0a5c 21d3' > /sys/bus/usb/drivers/btusb/new_id && echo '0a5c 21d7' > /sys/bus/usb/drivers/btusb/new_id && echo '0a5c 21e1' > /sys/bus/usb/drivers/btusb/new_id && echo '0a5c 21e3' > /sys/bus/usb/drivers/btusb/new_id && hciconfig hci0 up && /usr/bin/brcm_patchram_plus_usb --patchram /lib/firmware/BCM43142A0_001.001.011.0028.0036.hcd hci0 &
> ```
>
> Output of `lsusb`:
>
> ```
> ...
> Bus 002 Device 003: ID 0a5c:21d7 Broadcom Corp.
> ```
>
> **In conclusion:** bluetooth works not nearly as good as in Windows. Once I even got a complete crash of the system because of the btusb module. Luckily WiFi works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue on an Asus X202E (BCM43142 chip): with Ubuntu 12.10 x64, I had to install wireless driver as described above. Which works for wifi... but not for BT.

Now switched to 13.04 x64 and had wireless working without the need of installing wifi driver, Bluetooh still not working.
I'll try this evening the bt-bcm43142 package and see if I can get my BT working.

In anycase, thanks for the post, it's a nice resume of the BCM43142 challenge in Ubuntu.

**Update**

I have just installed the above mentionned package, rebooted and I now have BT working and connecting to devices :)

For readers who might face the same issue, here are some command output before installing the package:

```
$ lsusb
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 13d3:3388 IMC Networks 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 13d3:5188 IMC Networks 
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 03eb:8417 Atmel Corp.

$ lspci -nn
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [14e4:4365] (rev 01)
03:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Qualcomm Atheros AR8162 Fast Ethernet [1969:1090] (rev 10)

$ rfkill list
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: brcmwl-0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
3: asus-wlan: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
4: asus-bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
5: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

$ hcitool dev
Devices:
    hci0    DC:85:DE:AB:4D:38

$ hciconfig
hci0:   Type: BR/EDR  Bus: USB
    BD Address: DC:85:DE:AB:4D:38  ACL MTU: 1021:8  SCO MTU: 64:1
    UP RUNNING PSCAN 
    RX bytes:549 acl:0 sco:0 events:31 errors:0
    TX bytes:1168 acl:0 sco:0 commands:31 errors:0

$ sudo service bluetooth status
bluetooth start/running, process 944

$ dmesg | grep Blue
[    8.954020] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.16
[    8.954086] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[    8.954096] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[    8.954100] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[    8.954114] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[   10.975507] Bluetooth: hci0 command 0x1003 tx timeout
[   11.088728] Bluetooth: can't load firmware, may not work correctly
[   12.901647] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[   12.901653] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[   12.901664] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[   12.909989] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[   12.910004] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[   12.910007] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
[   15.226150] Bluetooth: hci0 command 0x1003 tx timeout
[44180.125379] Bluetooth: can't load firmware, may not work correctly
```

We can notice that firmware can be loaded as per last libe here above. But after having installing it and rebooting the computer... All Good :)

```
$ dmesg | grep Blue
[    8.768600] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.16
[    8.768625] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[    8.768634] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[    8.768638] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[    8.768644] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[    8.989943] Bluetooth: can't load firmware, may not work correctly
[   13.036311] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[   13.036327] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[   13.036330] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
[   13.037056] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[   13.037059] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[   13.037064] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
```

[wireless](/questions/tagged/wireless) [13.10](/questions/tagged/13.10) [bluetooth](/questions/tagged/bluetooth) [asus](/questions/tagged/asus) [x202e](/questions/tagged/x202e) [broadcom](/questions/tagged/broadcom) [bcm43142](/questions/tagged/bcm43142)