# wifi not working on dell laptop in ubuntu

Tags: 12.04, wireless, drivers, broadcom

I recently installed ubuntu 12.04 on my machine, but I am not able to use wi-fi in ubuntu. Actually there is a toggle button to turn on the wifi and when the wifi is ON an LED will glow. But all the time I presses that button it don't glow.

So I tried installing the driver form the solution suggested in question:
[How do I install BCM43142 wireless drivers for Dell Vostro 3460/3560](https://askubuntu.com/questions/175104/how-do-i-install-bcm43142-wireless-drivers-for-dell-vostro-3460-3560)

since the wifi device on my machine is also `Broadcom Corporation Device [14e4:4365]`. I got the driver successfully installed but still I am not able to turn on the wifi means the LED not glows.

Also here are the output of some commands which might be helpful

`lshw -C network`

```
*-network UNCLAIMED
   description: Network controller
   product: Broadcom Corporation
   vendor: Broadcom Corporation
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
   version: 01
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: bus_master cap_list
   configuration: latency=0
   resources: memory:f1900000-f1907fff
```

and `iwconfig`

```
lo        no wireless extensions.

usb0      no wireless extensions.
```

here usb0 is what I am using with my mobile connected with data cable to access internet.

And `rfkill list`

```
0: dell-wifi: Wireless LAN
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
1: dell-bluetooth: Bluetooth
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
```

Also one more thing when I toggle the wifi button off the `rfkill list` gives both in blocked mode.

Please help... Thanks.

Comment: rebooted the system? or try deb file from here - http://jas.gemnetworks.com/debian/pool/main/w/ as mentioned in http://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/how-to-install-broadcom-sta-wireless-card-bcm43xx

Comment: ok, i didn't tried rebooting after driver installation. Anyways I will check today if it is working.

Comment: Sometimes rebooting really works :D :P

Comment: yes, after installation you have to either execute `modprobe <driver_name>` or reboot. :)