# BCM43142 drivers for Ubuntu 12.10 32-bit

Tags: 12.10, wireless, drivers, 32-bit, dell-vostro

related to [How do I install BCM43142 wireless drivers for Dell Vostro 3460/3560?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/175104/how-do-i-install-bcm43142-wireless-drivers-for-dell-vostro-3460-3560) .

That question is not reflecting a solution for Ubuntu 12.10 32-bit.

Comment: I am not able to contribute in the original question due to lack of reputation. Someone may want to merge this.

What has worked for me is..

 1. Download the bcmwl-kernel-source package for Raring Ringtail (13.04) from https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/raring/i386/bcmwl-kernel-source/6.20.155.1+bdcom-0ubuntu6 
 2. sudo dpkg -i bcmwl-kernel-source_6.20.155.1+bdcom-0ubuntu6_i386.deb
 3. Reboot and enjoy

Comment: I don't believe there is a 32-bit solution. The smart people who created the .debs only created 64-bit. I believe your hardware supports 64-bit easily and I suggest you install it.

Comment: Well, my hardware indeed easily supports 64-bit, but I chose to run the 32-bit Ubuntu, that is another question anyway.

This solution has been verified on my Vostro 3460 running Ubuntu 12.10 on a 32-bit kernel.

As mentioned above, I would have preferred to add this note to the existing question http://askubuntu.com/questions/175104/how-do-i-install-bcm43142-wireless-drivers-for-dell-vostro-3460-3560 , but still lacking reputation.