# How do I get the BCM 4312 wireless card working on a Dell Mini 10v?

Tags: wireless, upgrade, 13.04, dell

I have looked at other posts similar to this, but no solution helped.

I upgraded to 13.04 on a Dell Inspiron Mini 10v. Now I don't have wifi connectivity. It is absolutely essential that I have wifi on this computer. I've tried the code suggested at this link, [Dell 3721 Wifi problem Ubuntu 13.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/289609/dell-3721-wifi-problem-ubuntu-13-04) but it didn't work. What can I do?

I think

```
 this is the extra information needed:
 *-network UNCLAIMED     
       description: Network controller
       product: BCM4312 802.11b/g LP-PHY
       vendor: Broadcom Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       version: 01
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:f0100000-f0103fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8101E/RTL8102E PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
       logical name: eth0
       version: 02
       serial: 00:24:e8:f2:4c:c5
       size: 100Mbit/s
       capacity: 100Mbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=full firmware=N/A ip=192.168.11.9 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=100Mbit/s
       resources: irq:43 ioport:2000(size=256) memory:f0510000-f0510fff memory:f0500000-f050ffff memory:f0520000-f053ffff
```

Comment: We need more hardware information to help you, can you look at [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/14008/i-have-a-hardware-detection-problem-what-logs-do-i-need-to-look-into) and then edit your question adding the information.

Comment: @JorgeCastro Info added.

Comment: Try the stuff therre ^^ and update your question with the results, thanks!

Comment: I have tried work out what those instructions mean, and they are not clear to me. They might be relevant to that person and their level of expertise, but they haven't helped me.

Comment: How can I get any help? The issue is not resolved. This is for a computer that when it is connected to the net, it's almost always via wifi, and at times tethered wifi.