# wifi is not working in 12.04.3 LTS 64 bit version

Tags: wireless

The same driver for my wireless card that worked in the 32 bit version of ubuntu 12.04, fail to install after I upgraded to the 64 bit version. 
*Broadcom STA Driver  This package contains Broadcom 802.11 Linux STA wireless driver for use with Broadcom's BCM4311-, BCM4312-, BCM4313-, BCM4321-, BCM4322-, BCM43224-, and BCM43225-, BCM43227- and BCM43228-based hardware.*
lcpi: My wireless is Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM43142 802.11b/g/n (rev 01)
If this package isn't for my wifi card then how do I get a package that will will be compatible? where would I start looking?
My laptop is a dell inspiron 3520
Description

```
Intel Core i3-2350M Dual Core Processor
4GB PC3-12800 DDR3 Memory
500GB 5400rpm SATA Hard Drive
8x DVD+/-RW Dual Layer Burner
15.6" WXGA (1366x768) Display With 1.0 Megapixel Webcam
Intel HD Graphics 3000 Integrated Graphics
Fast Ethernet, 802.11b/g/n Wireless, Bluetooth
Three USB 2.0, HDMI, VGA, 3-in-1 Card Reader
14.8" x 10.2" x 1.4" @ 5.2 lbs.
```

ERROR MESSAGE
Sorry, installation of this driver failed.

Please have a look at the log file for details: /var/log/jockey.log
I hope this is helpful "2013-09-01 12:09:04,635 DEBUG: BroadcomWLHandler enabled(): kmod disabled, bcm43xx: blacklisted, b43: blacklisted, b43legacy: blacklisted"

Comment: This is a bug - https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/bcmwl/+bug/1095751 - you'll see the same error in /var/log/jockey.log.  You'll need to downgrade to an earlier kernel to fix this - i.e. 3.2 or the lts-quantal kernel.

Comment: Please see here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/175104/how-do-i-install-bcm43142-wireless-drivers-for-dell-vostro-3460-3560 Be sure to use the answer for 12.04.

Comment: I tried to install the 32 bit version @fossfreedom but it black screens and doesn't do anything but spin the disc for a few mins. Do you think it'll ever be fixed or just be a diversion from 13.04? I think my pc should be running a 64 bit OS, at least I thought.

Comment: Chris - "3.2" in my comment referred to kernel 3.2.  However, see the other two comments, there are other workarounds suggested.