# Ubuntu 12.04 blocks bootable USB

Tags: 12.04

Today I installed ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS on my brand new Ideapad g580. However, I discovered that I can't get my WIFI to work, and I don't have an Ethernet cable to get an internet connection. This led me to downloading Xubuntu 12.04 and hoping my WIFI will work on that one. However, after I downloaded it and made  a bootable usb, the USB won't boot. When using Linux Live Creator I get an efi disk read error, and when using UNetBooting I can't access the boot menu to change the booting disk.

I am ready to provide any info You might need to help me solve any of these issues (the other being my WIFI not working, which is a common issue, but fixing it requires downloading the necessary files from a different computer and providing them via USB as most fixes include aptget).

```
Linux Imroth 3.11.0-15-generic #25~precise1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jan 30 17:39:31 UTC 2014     x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
imroth@Imroth:~$ lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor DRAM Controller (rev 09)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v2/3rd Gen Core processor PCI Express Root Port (rev 09)
00:01.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v2/3rd Gen Core processor PCI Express Root Port (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller (rev 09)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI Host Controller (rev 04)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family High  Definition Audio Controller (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev c4)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 2 (rev c4)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation HM76 Express Chipset LPC Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series Chipset Family 6-port SATA    Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 04)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 04)
01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GF117M [GeForce 610M/710M / GT 620M/625M/630M/720M] (rev a1)
03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Qualcomm Atheros AR8162 Fast Ethernet (rev 10)
04:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM43142 802.11b/g/n (rev 01)
```

Now that I think about it, would xUbuntu do me any better? As I understand it, it's based on Ubuntu...

Comment: Please run `uname -a`, `lspci` on your Ubuntu, and paste it here

Answer (score 0):

Where did you download your Ubuntu installation image? Latest 12.04.4 should have this drivers?

You can check [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/175104/how-do-i-install-bcm43142-wireless-drivers-for-dell-vostro-3460-3560) answer. As I can see Dell Vostro 3460/3560 has same Broadcom Corporation BCM43142. So check @izx's answer, download drivers and install it.

Or you can download latest XUbuntu 13.10 if you want use XUbuntu.

Or you can wait until April 17-th, 14.04 LTS release date.