# Drivers for Broadcom BCM43142 on Ubuntu 14.04 (Trusty Tahr)

Tags: wireless, networking, drivers, broadcom, broadband

I am not able to install drivers for my Wi-Fi + Bluetooth card (Broadcom BCM43142).

What I have done till now:

1. I have tried using the drivers at [this](http://www.broadcom.com/support/802.11/linux_sta.php) website.
2. I tried following the instructions given [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Driver/bcm43xx) for both the `apt-get` install, download tar ball and install and offline install (from Ubuntu's boot DVD).
3. I tried installing `bcmwl-kernel-source`.

At the end of every single method [1,2,3], when I do a `sudo modprobe wl`, I invariably get this:

> modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'wl': Exec format error.

I have also tried blacklisting drivers other than `wl` and have tried reinstalling the same several times.

4. I also tried using `ndiswrapper` which was successful enough to make the UNCLAIMED driver (see below for the output of `lshw -c Network`) change to something else.

However at the end the Wi-Fi did now show up or work.

Kernel version: `3.13.0-24-generic`

I have tried everything I could do to my full ability. It would be extremely helpful if you could help me setup my Wi-Fi. I am willing to pastebin output of any commands that you might ask me to execute. (I have added the outputs of `lshw -c Network` and `lspci -nn` , but please don't hesitate to ask me anything else.)

```
lshw -c Network
WARNING: you should run this program as super-user.
  *-network UNCLAIMED     
       description: Network controller
       product: BCM43142 802.11b/g/n
       vendor: Broadcom Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       version: 01
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:90500000-90507fff

lspci
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [14e4:4365] (rev 01)
```

The output of sudo apt-get install `bcmwl-kernel-source`. The official driver (by Ubuntu) for this WLAN card:

```
sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  wireless-bcm43142-oneiric-dkms
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  bcmwl-kernel-source
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 1 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/1,126 kB of archives.
After this operation, 1,417 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 318223 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing wireless-bcm43142-oneiric-dkms (6.20.55.19~bdcom0602.0400.1000.0400-0somerville1) ...
Removing all DKMS Modules
Done.
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.103ubuntu4) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-24-generic
Selecting previously unselected package bcmwl-kernel-source.
(Reading database ... 318162 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../bcmwl-kernel-source_6.30.223.141+bdcom-0ubuntu2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking bcmwl-kernel-source (6.30.223.141+bdcom-0ubuntu2) ...
Setting up bcmwl-kernel-source (6.30.223.141+bdcom-0ubuntu2) ...
Loading new bcmwl-6.30.223.141+bdcom DKMS files...
Building only for 3.13.0-24-generic
Building for architecture x86_64
Building initial module for 3.13.0-24-generic
Done.

wl:
Running module version sanity check.
 - Original module
 - Installation
   - Installing to /lib/modules/3.13.0-24-generic/updates/dkms/

depmod.......

DKMS: install completed.
```

This is the error I keep getting repeatedly:

**`modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'wl': Exec format error`**

```
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.103ubuntu4) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-24-generic
```

Also, what is meant by the same?

I went through the following *Ask Ubuntu* questions:

- *[How do I install BCM43142 wireless drivers for Dell Vostro 3460/3560?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/175104)*
- *[Installing Broadcom Wireless Drivers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868)*

The second one seems to be a very comprehensive summary of all possible ways... Still I am stuck up with this `Exec Format error`.

Comment: This particular driver was already covered on this site [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/175104/how-do-i-install-bcm43142-wireless-drivers-for-dell-vostro-3460-3560). Have you tried that?

Comment: @Jos The 1st answer doesnt work for me ! (same modprobe error). The  second seems to work for a lot of ppl. I have seen the same at other forums too. But unfortunately the link is dead ... Thanks for the reply :)

Comment: To me, none of the links are dead - in particular, the links to the .deb files both work (the ones in someone's Dropbox). Which seems something you could easily try.

Comment: The dropbox deb package doesnt work and again throws this error when I do `modprobe wl` that I previously mentioned. I meant this http://jas.gemnetworks.com link. Does it work for you ?

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean now. Never mind.

Comment: You need to run `sudo apt-get updtae` and it's important to update **pci list** `sudo update-pciids` then install driver: `sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source`

Comment: I was able to get the WLAN on my new Lenovo G50-70 i5 to run by following the advice of Ayushya Chitransh in the Link http://askubuntu.com/questions/553615

Answer (score 23, accepted):

OK, so I finally fixed this :D

First here's what I learnt in the process:

1. NEVER ram your OS with different drivers or modules haphazardly until your problem gets fixed, **at least not** without a) Knowing what / why you are doing, and b) MOST IMPORTANTLY *How to undo the same.*
2. Whenever you try a different driver, module, or package, *first uninstall the package that you previously installed for the same purpose*.

And lots of thanks to @[chili555](https://askubuntu.com/users/19421/chili555) who pointed out that the leftover from a previous package was the reason.

So what I did was:

1. I tried installing `bcmwl-kernel-source` on a live run of Ubuntu 14.04 (with my LAN cable) and checked if WLan works now. (And yeah, it did **confirm that Ubuntu 14.04 / BCM43142 / `bcmwl-kernel-source` were not the problem**.)
2. I went to `/etc/modprobe.d` and cross checked the files there with my hard disk installation's version of the same folder.
3. This `/etc/modprobe.d` directory contains configuration files which contain blacklisting information for different modules. I made a note of the available files and later removed what was not available here from my hard disk installation's version of the same folder too.
4. I went to `/lib/modules/3.*/updates/`. **This** is the directory that stores all your modules (wl, b43, etc. ... ) and the one that I messed up with various custom patched versions of wl modules listed in various forums.
5. After cross checking with my hard disk installation's version of `lib/modules/3.*/updates/`, I manually removed all Bluetooth / wireless / dkms / wl / (and in particular one mac80211) and cleaned up any other modules that are related to wlan.
6. I finally replaced (did a recursive copy *onto*) the `/etc/modprobe.d` and `/lib/modules/3.*/updates/` directories (of my hard disk installation) with the same directories from the live OS.
7. Reboot
8. Do `sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source`. This is the official working driver for BCM43142 for Ubuntu 14.04.
9. Reboot and `sudo modprobe wl` and viola, wireless was working!

And finally sincere apologies to all my cross-posting, reposting, spamming IRCs with this question repeatedly. :P

NOTE: Replacing /removing your hard disk installation files is recommended only for those who installed your OS recently. Otherwise there is a risk that you could replace / remove files / modules that may have been installed for other devices which may be irrelevant to this issue.

Thanks again to chili555 :)

**EDIT** I recently updated my kernel to support the `DisplayLink` driver for my USB monitor and bam the wifi was gone.

A blind attempt at re-installing `bcmwl-kernel-source` threw the following error in the build log.

```
"alloc_netdev" requires 4 arguments, but only 3 given
```

Turns out the driver was not updated for the upgraded kernel (version 3.18). A bit of googling let me to this post -

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/bcmwl/+bug/1358966

Where there are links available to patched versions of `wl`, which works with the upgraded kernel.

I manually downloaded and installed [this](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty-updates/amd64/bcmwl-kernel-source/download) guy and wifi was restored.

Now I can go back to browsing lolcats in peace. Amen.

Comment: I was more lucky. After an update I lost my wifi connection. Via USB threatening I just did your 8 step: sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source --- and bump! It works without a need of a reboot.

Comment: This answer is the most reliable I've found but it hasn't worked for me, I'm dealing with a Lenovo Z40 and a freshly installed Ubuntu 16.04. Any pointers to upgrade the answer?

Comment: @IdeaW It might be possible that you have an upgraded version of  linux kernel that is incompatible with the unpatched `wl` module. Maybe try my last edit and see if it works for you?

Answer (score 6):

I too had the same trouble when installing Linux Mint, Ubuntu 13.10 and 14.04.
I had to use a LAN cable or USB tethering from my phone to get **bcmwl-kernel-source** installed which seemed to be the only working wireless driver for my DELL inspiron 15.

however i was able to see the **bcmwl-kernel-source** in the additional drivers section of the software updates after running

```
sudo apt-get update
```

from the terminal after establishing internet connection via LAN or USB tethering and you will see the additional drivers listed from where i was able to install the driver pretty easily.

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same issue with Ubuntu 11.10 and 12.10. The problem was that Wi-Fi was not detected on BCM43142 Sony VAIO FIT 15E. Therefore, when I tried to install Ubuntu 13.10, I checked the option of "Install this third party software" during installation, and it worked for me!!

See step 2 on *[Install Ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-desktop-latest)*, sub section *Prepare to install Ubuntu*. You can also try this.

Comment: Ummm.. I remember having chosen that third party option I guess, since I installed this Ubuntu 14 only recently. But is there anyway to do the same now again without having to reinstall ubuntu ?

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered the issue and to solve it I just run the next command:

```
# (sudo rmmod b43 ; sudo rmmod bcma ; sudo rmmod wl ; sudo modprobe wl ; sudo modprobe lib80211_crypt_tkip)
```

It seems that b43 or bcma are collisions to the wl module.

Hope it will help someone...

Answer (score 0):

Similar Problem on Ubuntu 20.04 with HP notebook.
Solution:
pre:
Identify your chipset:

```
lspci -vvnn | grep -A 9 Network
```

You will get the chip ID on first or second line. (eg BCM4331)
Actual Solution
Install (if there is internet access through ethernet) Broadcom STA Wireless driver (Proprietary):

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get --reinstall install bcmwl-kernel-source
```

Test and avoid reboot through :

```
sudo modprobe -r b43 ssb wl brcmfmac brcmsmac bcma
sudo modprobe wl
```

This is taken from :

[this Ubuntu help page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Driver/bcm43xx)