# Ubuntu - Method to install drivers

Tags: drivers, broadcom, ethernet

How do I install ethernet driver on Ubuntu? Isn there a program which installs the drivers?The .exe files dont work.There are linux editions but i do not know how to install them.

Comment: Does the Ethernet port on your computer works with Ubuntu? For normal cases, it should be already included in the kernel, unless you're talking about the Broadcom wireless card.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! ;-) Could you please give us a bit more information like: what version of Ubuntu you're running? What the output of `sudo lshw -c network` is?  Please [edit] your question and add this information...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are detailed guides on how to install your wifi driver. To let your situation better be known, please specify your laptop company and model, so that your ethernet adapter model may be looked at. If your driver is broadcom BCM43142 then

> `sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source`

This will install wifi driver offline. You may also get your answer at this question
[Cant enable proprietary driver for broadcom bcm43142](https://askubuntu.com/questions/553615/cant-enable-the-proprietary-drivers-for-broadcom-bcm43142-wireless-after-instal/556417#556417)
I hope it helps!