# HP Stream 14 (BCM43142) WiFi driver

Tags: wireless, 15.04, laptop, broadcom

I have installed Ubuntu 15.04 for a HP Stream 14 Laptop. The WiFi network driver is not recognised automatically, so there´s no Internet.

By making **`sudo lshw`**, the Network Controller is: BCM43142 802.11b/g/n - Broadcom Corporation

I would need to download into a USB drive from other computer and then run into the HP Stream. What do I need to download and execute to make it work into Ubuntu?

Thanks,

Comment: This is resolved in: http://askubuntu.com/questions/553615/cant-enable-the-proprietary-drivers-for-broadcom-bcm43142-wireless-after-instal (although question was for **14.10**)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Installing Broadcom Wireless Drivers](http://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers)

Answer (score -1):

The simplest and easy way to install Wi-Fi driver is to use `Ndiswrapper`

[Install Ndiswrapper](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/saucy/ndisgtk/)

1. download your Wi-Fi driver (windows version)
2. Launch Ndiswrapper tool.
3. Click on `Install new driver` brows to you Wi-Fi driver
4. your are done.

Comment: *Which can muck up your Ubuntu install, and should be used as a next-to-last resort.*

Answer (score -1):

I finally got around this WIFI driver issue with ubuntu 15.10 version. It's little tricky so just follow the steps I have put here.

1. Create a bootable USB for Ubuntu 15.10 - Just follow the instructions on Ubuntu website.
2. Plug in the USB, power up the laptop and keep hitting F9, You will see an option to boot from USB - Select and hit Enter.
3. This will load Ubuntu bootloader - on the top you will see WIFI symbol and at this point, it would show a note "No Network Device Detected". Don't worry about it - we will get to it.
4. For now, just follow the instructions on the screen, select language, keyboard setting and Drive the erase - Just stop here.
5. Right at the prompt where UBUNTU says - "Erase Drive and Install Ubuntu" - Just click the "BACK" button
6. Keep going back to the previous screen, until you see an option to select wireless network.
7. Choose your network, enter password and continue with the installation.

It worked for me, so I thought I would put the instructions here.