# No wifi after installing Ubuntu 18.04lts on ho stream

Tags: wireless, 18.04

I'm totally new to all forms of Linux. I'm familiar with terminal and entering commands (to the extent of copying commands from the forum and typing them into my terminal in the hope something good happens).

I just installed Ubuntu 18.04 lts on my HP stream 14ax 060nr. I haven't made any modifications to the laptop hardware. I no longer have the option to use wifi. It does give me the option to use Bluetooth.

Can anybody help me out with noob-suitable ideas on how to fix this?

Prior to this I tried elementary and had the same issue (except that I didn't have the Bluetooth option on elementary).

WiFi and Bluetooth worked perfectly when I was using Windows 10

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had to manually turn on my wifi with network manager and add the device.

Start with "sudo nmcli radio wifi on".  From there, you can manually add the interface via the gui.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks so much for getting back to me, I appreciate it. Sadly that command doesn't return any results though. And the wifi tab in settings still reads 'no wifi adapter found. Make sure you have a wifi adapter and it is turned on'

Answer (score 0):

A wired ethernet adapter, USB or otherwise, seems like a handy thing to have if you need a WiFi driver that's somehow not there (in order for apt-get update to work, too...and it's likely fast?)

If you try (without need to be superuser, in Ubuntu 18.04)

```
dmesg | most
```

you should be able to see a bit of what's going on; hit / to search for terms like wireless or unable (as in unable to load suitable wifi driver for device _____) and see if that gets you handy things like the name of the module (surely bcmwl?) and what happened when it tried to load that kernel network module.
  Feel free to append dmesg or excerpted output to your question. I would also try

```
wicd
```

and see if my options opened up for that small effort.

I spotted [HP Stream 14 (BCM43142) WiFi driver](https://askubuntu.com/questions/666327/hp-stream-14-bcm43142-wifi-driver) also, which suggests booting from the install media again, backing off from installing, and picking/installing a network driver from there.

Comment: Thanks so much for helping out. The dmesg command does bring a ton of text up, but I don't see anything relating to wifi card, wlan or networking. The closest thing is wifi hot keys. Wicd asks me to try again with 'sudo apt install wicd-daemon' and when I do it returns 'building dependency information.  Reading state information... Done.    E: Unable to locate package wicd-daemon' .  I'll try booting from the install media and doing as you suggest later today.

Comment: In trying to boot from the USB and install the drivers I had some difficulty. In the process of trying to do this (which I'd previously done with ease) I turned off secure boot. After turning off secure boot the wifi works perfectly. Sorry for wasting your time! And thanks again