# wifi problem with rlg

Tags: 14.04, networking, broadcom

I have freshly installed 14.04 on an rlg laptop. after installing, the wifi is not working and I dont also have wired access to internet. the output of lspci -knn | grep Net -A2 is :

```
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4322 802.11a/b/g/n Wireless LAN Controller [14e4:432b] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:1510]
    Kernel driver in use: b43-pci-bridge
```

could you please help me activate the wifi?

Comment: I don't have accerss to internet with this laptop, so I can't use the solution suggested over there

Comment: In that case, try https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Driver/bcm43xx#b43_-_No_Internet_access

Comment: This may also be helpful:  http://askubuntu.com/questions/553615/cant-enable-the-proprietary-drivers-for-broadcom-bcm43142-wireless-after-instal/553619#553619