# Trying on a stick before I install; can't find wireless

Tags: networking, drivers, live-usb

I've successfully booted into ubuntu, but I can't connect wirelessly.

This is a new HP 550-135wb desktop with onboard wireless b/g/n and lan. [HP Pavilion 550-153wb](http://www.walmart.com/ip/HP-Pavilion-550-153wb-Desktop-PC-with-Intel-Core-i3-4170-Dual-Core-Processor-6GB-Memory-23-Monitor-1TB-Hard-Drive-and-Windows-10-Home/46429968#about)

The ubuntu gui only shows wired and network proxy options.

iwconfig reports

`eth0    no wireless extensions`

`lo      no wireless extensions`

The motherboard for this desktop is labeled ipm87-mp

Do I need to download some drivers?

Comment: further information:

lspci -v

02:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM43142 802.11b/g/n (rev 01)
Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 2b2c

Answer (score 0):

I had to find out what the wireless controller was by using `lspci -v`

This gave me the information to google, and I finally came up with [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/553615/cant-enable-the-proprietary-drivers-for-broadcom-bcm43142-wireless-after-instal)

> Do you still have the install USB or DVD? Insert it and drill down to pool > restricted > b > bcmwl and drag bcmwl-kernel-source to your desktop. Do the same with pool > main > d >dkms and drag dkms to you desktop. Then install:

```
cd ~/Desktop
sudo dpkg -i dkms*.deb
sudo dpkg -i bcmwl*.deb
```

> Reboot and tell us if your wireless is working.