# problem with Broadcom 802.11ac Network on Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: networking, drivers, lenovo, broadcom

*i have a question i'm trying to convert my Lenovo 500-15ACZ Laptop (ideapad) - Type 80K4 - Modell 80K4005PMT (Serial#MP13K4RK) but i have problem with WIFI every time i'm installing Ubuntu 17.10  i get problem with wifi as it doesn't work at all i have tried to use cable or wireless but to no avail and i can't find any driver that support Broadcom 802.11ac Network Adapter so thos this men  it is impasibol or can i change my wifi card or use an external wifi adapter like Panda 300Mbps Wireless N USB Adapter  to solve my problem sin everything else work fine i think except wifi P.S i want to try ubuntu as i am litel bit tired of windows but i'm a noob :( with dyslexia so please be nice about my spelling*

Comment: Did you try the driver bcmwl-kernel-source? Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: _no i havent try that that suluton but  whats driver bcmwl-kernel-source is it one of command line listed her https://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/amd64/bcmwl-kernel-source/filelist or have i misundersand what it is_

Comment: Please see: https://askubuntu.com/questions/553615/cant-enable-the-proprietary-drivers-for-broadcom-bcm43142-wireless-after-instal/553619#553619