# Wireless card Broadcom 43142

Tags: wireless, drivers, broadcom

On my new Asus A450J, I have a wireless network card Broadcom 43142 (14e4:4365).
This WiFi card works well under the pre-installed Win 8.1.

In a brand new installation of an Ubuntu, my wifi card cannot work.
I have tried several things (external deb packages, ndiswrapper, several installations of Ubuntu) to make it work but am always stuck with the same problem: the card looks well recognized but I cannot activate it.

The following package is natively installed: bcmwl-kernel-source, ver 6.30.223. From [previous post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/459654/drivers-for-broadcom-bcm43142-on-ubuntu-14-04-trusty-tahr), this should be sufficient for the card to work, but it is not.

A modprobe makes believe everything is fine:

```
$ sudo modprobe wl
$ echo $?
0
```

but the card keeps being desactivated:

```
$ sudo lshw -C network
  *-network DISABLED      
       description: Wireless interface
       product: BCM43142 802.11b/g/n
       vendor: Broadcom Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: wlan0
       version: 01
       serial: 30:10:b3:0b:da:66
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=wl0 driverversion=6.30.223.141 (r415941) latency=0 multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11abg
       resources: irq:18 memory:f7900000-f7907fff
[...]
```

Through the Network Settings window, if I turn on the wireless card, it turns back off quasi-instantly.

Thanks in advance for any tip to get this solved.
Additional (useful?) information on my system:

```
wget -N -t 5 -T 10 http://dl.dropbox.com/u/57264241/wireless_script && chmod +x wireless_script && ./wireless_script
```

yields the following wireless-info.txt (see also http://paste.ubuntu.com/9678828/):

```
########## wireless info START ##########

Report from: 31 Dec 2014 18:14 CET +0100

Booted last: 31 Dec 2014 18:09 CET +0100

Script from: 20 Sep 2014 23:04 UTC +0000

##### release ###########################

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty

##### kernel ############################

Linux 3.13.0-43-generic #72-Ubuntu SMP Mon Dec 8 19:35:06 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Parameters: ro, quiet, splash, vt.handoff=7

##### desktop ###########################

Ubuntu

##### lspci #############################

03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [14e4:4365] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Lite-On Communications Inc Device [11ad:6605]
    Kernel driver in use: wl

04:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Qualcomm Atheros QCA8171 Gigabit Ethernet [1969:10a1] (rev 10)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device [1043:200f]
    Kernel driver in use: alx

##### lsusb #############################

Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8008 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 04f2:b3d8 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 04ca:2006 Lite-On Technology Corp. 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

##### PCMCIA card info ##################

##### rfkill ############################

0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: brcmwl-0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: acer-wireless: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no

##### lsmod #############################

asus_nb_wmi            16990  0 
acer_wmi               32522  0 
asus_wmi               24191  1 asus_nb_wmi
sparse_keymap          13948  2 acer_wmi,asus_wmi
wl                   4207846  0 
lib80211               14381  2 wl,lib80211_crypt_tkip
cfg80211              484040  1 wl
mxm_wmi                13021  1 nouveau
wmi                    19177  4 acer_wmi,mxm_wmi,nouveau,asus_wmi
video                  19476  4 i915,acer_wmi,nouveau,asus_wmi

##### interfaces ########################

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

##### ifconfig ##########################

eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr <MAC 'eth0' [IF]>  
          inet addr:192.168.0.39  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::ae9e:17ff:fe41:2cae/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
          Interrupt:19 

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr <MAC 'wlan0' [IF]>  
          BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
          Interrupt:18 

##### iwconfig ##########################

eth0      no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.

wlan0     IEEE 802.11abg  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   
          Retry  long limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off


##### route #############################

Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.0.254   0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     1      0        0 eth0

##### resolv.conf #######################

nameserver 127.0.1.1

##### nm-tool ###########################

NetworkManager Tool

State: connected (global)

- Device: eth0  [Wired connection 1] -------------------------------------------
  Type:              Wired
  Driver:            alx
  State:             connected
  Default:           yes
  HW Address:        <MAC 'eth0' [IF]>

  Capabilities:
    Carrier Detect:  yes
    Speed:           100 Mb/s

  Wired Properties
    Carrier:         on

  IPv4 Settings:
    Address:         192.168.0.39
    Prefix:          24 (255.255.255.0)
    Gateway:         192.168.0.254

    DNS:             212.27.40.241
    DNS:             212.27.40.240

- Device: wlan0 ----------------------------------------------------------------
  Type:              802.11 WiFi
  Driver:            wl
  State:             unavailable
  Default:           no
  HW Address:        <MAC 'wlan0' [IF]>

  Capabilities:

  Wireless Properties
    WEP Encryption:  yes
    WPA Encryption:  yes
    WPA2 Encryption: yes

  Wireless Access Points 

##### NetworkManager.state ##############

[main]
NetworkingEnabled=true
WirelessEnabled=true
WWANEnabled=true
WimaxEnabled=true

##### NetworkManager.conf ###############

[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile,ofono
dns=dnsmasq

[ifupdown]
managed=false

##### NetworkManager profiles ###########

##### iw reg get ########################

Region: Europe/Paris (based on set time zone)

country 00:
    (2402 - 2472 @ 40), (3, 20)
    (2457 - 2482 @ 40), (3, 20), PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS
    (2474 - 2494 @ 20), (3, 20), NO-OFDM, PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS
    (5170 - 5250 @ 40), (3, 20), PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS
    (5735 - 5835 @ 40), (3, 20), PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS

##### iwlist channels ###################

eth0      no frequency information.

lo        no frequency information.

wlan0     26 channels in total; available frequencies :
          Channel 01 : 2.412 GHz
          Channel 02 : 2.417 GHz
          Channel 03 : 2.422 GHz
          Channel 04 : 2.427 GHz
          Channel 05 : 2.432 GHz
          Channel 06 : 2.437 GHz
          Channel 07 : 2.442 GHz
          Channel 08 : 2.447 GHz
          Channel 09 : 2.452 GHz
          Channel 10 : 2.457 GHz
          Channel 11 : 2.462 GHz
          Channel 12 : 2.467 GHz
          Channel 13 : 2.472 GHz
          Channel 14 : 2.484 GHz
          Channel 36 : 5.18 GHz
          Channel 38 : 5.19 GHz
          Channel 40 : 5.2 GHz
          Channel 42 : 5.21 GHz
          Channel 44 : 5.22 GHz
          Channel 46 : 5.23 GHz
          Channel 48 : 5.24 GHz
          Channel 149 : 5.745 GHz
          Channel 153 : 5.765 GHz
          Channel 157 : 5.785 GHz
          Channel 161 : 5.805 GHz
          Channel 165 : 5.825 GHz

##### iwlist scan #######################

eth0      Interface doesn't support scanning.

lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

wlan0     Interface doesn't support scanning : Network is down

##### module infos ######################

[wl]
filename:       /lib/modules/3.13.0-43-generic/updates/dkms/wl.ko
license:        MIXED/Proprietary
srcversion:     FF25FE784DC6BDFF69DAFCB
depends:        cfg80211,lib80211
vermagic:       3.13.0-43-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
parm:           wl_txq_thresh:int
parm:           oneonly:int
parm:           piomode:int
parm:           instance_base:int
parm:           nompc:int
parm:           intf_name:string

[cfg80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/3.13.0-43-generic/kernel/net/wireless/cfg80211.ko
description:    wireless configuration support
license:        GPL
author:         Johannes Berg
srcversion:     C2478077E22138832B71659
depends:        
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.13.0-43-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key
sig_key:        55:AB:2F:E2:8E:D5:C6:0D:F9:58:71:50:D1:73:4C:92:0E:A7:B8:18
sig_hashalgo:   sha512
parm:           ieee80211_regdom:IEEE 802.11 regulatory domain code (charp)
parm:           cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz:Disable 40MHz support in the 2.4GHz band (bool)

##### module parameters #################

[cfg80211]
cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz: N
ieee80211_regdom: 00

##### /etc/modules ######################

lp
rtc

##### modprobe options ##################

[/etc/modprobe.d/asus.conf]
options asus_nb_wmi wapf=1

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ath_pci.conf]
blacklist ath_pci

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-bcm43.conf]
blacklist b43
blacklist b43legacy
blacklist ssb
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist brcm80211
blacklist brcmfmac
blacklist brcmsmac
blacklist bcma

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf]
blacklist evbug
blacklist usbmouse
blacklist usbkbd
blacklist eepro100
blacklist de4x5
blacklist eth1394
blacklist snd_intel8x0m
blacklist snd_aw2
blacklist i2c_i801
blacklist prism54
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist garmin_gps
blacklist asus_acpi
blacklist snd_pcsp
blacklist pcspkr
blacklist amd76x_edac

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-rare-network.conf]
alias net-pf-3 off
alias net-pf-6 off
alias net-pf-9 off
alias net-pf-11 off
alias net-pf-12 off
alias net-pf-19 off
alias net-pf-21 off
alias net-pf-36 off

[/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf]
remove iwlwifi \
(/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \
&& /sbin/modprobe -r mac80211

[/etc/modprobe.d/mlx4.conf]
softdep mlx4_core post: mlx4_en

##### rc.local ##########################

exit 0

##### pm-utils ##########################

##### udev rules ########################

[/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules]
# PCI device 0x1969:0x10a1 (alx)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="<MAC 'eth0' [IF]>", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="eth*", NAME="eth0"
# PCI device 0x14e4:0x4365 (wl)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="<MAC 'wlan0' [IF]>", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="wlan*", NAME="wlan0"

##### dmesg #############################

[   13.374900] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
[  307.358883] ERROR @wl_dev_intvar_get : error (-1)

########## wireless info END ############


$lspci |grep Broadcom
03:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM43142 802.11b/g/n (rev 01)

lspci -vn
[...]
03:00.0 0280: 14e4:4365 (rev 01)
    Subsystem: 11ad:6605
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 18
    Memory at f7900000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=32K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: wl
[...]

$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty


$ dpkg --get-selections|grep bcm
bcmwl-kernel-source             install
libcmis-0.4-4                   install
```

Comment: Can you please run the [wireless network diagnostics script](/q/425155)? and [edit] your question to include a link to the result?

Answer (score 0):

The notation in *lshw* of *-network DISABLED usually means that the wireless device is blocked by the hardware switch or key combination; Fn+F4 or some such. You can check from the terminal:

```
rfkill list all
```

I am sure you have tried pressing the key to no avail.

Asus laptops have a helper module that is supposed to translate key presses into action, namely, turn on the wireless. It often doesn't function quite correctly until a parameter is set. Please try:

```
echo "options asus_nb_wmi wapf=1" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/asus.conf
```

Reboot and see if your wireless key combination and therefore the wireless are working as expected.

If wapf=1 is ineffective, you can try wapf=4, known to work in some cases, by overwriting the file with a 4 instead:

```
echo "options asus_nb_wmi wapf=4" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/asus.conf
```

Reboot and see if your wireless key combination and therefore the wireless are working as expected.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately it does not work. The Fn+F2 to switch the interface activation does not do anything (the activation LED keeps being on).

Comment: @MatthieuBrunet Please see my edit above.

Comment: thanks. I have followed your request. Neither wapf=1 nor wapf=4 worked.