# Problem with Broadcom BCM43142 wireless driver on 14.04

Tags: 14.04, wireless, broadcom

I have been facing some issues with the wireless drivers on my lenovo Z5070 laptop. Here is the history of the problem

1. After installing 14.04 Wifi was not working. So I followed the below article and installed `bcmwl-kernel-source`.

[Installing Broadcom Wireless Drivers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers)

2. After installing this driver, I am able to connect to Wifi. But the connection drops every now and then. I searched online and found the below article. But the issue in the referred  article uses a different wifi chipset.

[Drivers for Broadcom BCM43142 on Ubuntu 14.04 (Trusty Tahr)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/459654/drivers-for-broadcom-bcm43142-on-ubuntu-14-04-trusty-tahr)

Please help me fix this. I installed all the upgrades to check if that fixes the issue. But it didn't help. I also tried disabling the ipv6.

Answer (score 1):

I've been struggling with the same issue with Broadcom BCM43142 on my HP Envy 15 Touchsmart, Ubuntu 14.04. The Wifi card performance deteriorated after an update I did with Software Updater.

I tried purging and reinstalling bcmwl-kernel-source, installing firmware-b43-install and b43-fwcutter in various combinations. Nothing worked.

In the end, I had to downgrade bcmwl-kernel-source to a lower version by doing the following in the terminal:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge bcmwl-kernel-source
sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source=6.30.223.141+bdcom-0ubuntu2
sudo reboot
```

It's not ideal, but the wifi now works as it did before the update.

Comment: I found that this was happening because of the laptop was far away from the router. Once I moved to the other room in my house there were no issues.

Answer (score 1):

I had no wifi after upgrading the kernel. **`rfkill`** always showed **`hard blocked: yes`**
and I was unable to turn it off, not even through BIOS. I tried everything but I finally found the solution that worked immediately.

All you need to do is ***COVER THE PIN 20 OF THE WIFI PCI-CARD with some tape*.**

Answer (score 0):

I have been facing the same issue with my wireless and was able to solve it by upgrading the kernel to 3.18

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager/+bug/1297286

Kernel update:

Step 1)
go to URL: kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.18-vivid/

Step 2)
Choose the kernel suitable for your system (32-bit or 64-bit)

In my case I chose: linux-image-3.18.0-031800-generic_3.18.0-031800.201412071935_amd64.deb

Step 3)
Download it

Step 4)
Open it using the Ubuntu Software Center for installing it.

Step 5)
Reboot

Step 6)
Check kernel version: Open Terminal with CTRL-ALT-T, type "uname -a" and then hit  in the command prompt. The kernel version should be on 3.18 now and your wifi issue hopefully fixed.

I am now enjoying a stable 802.11n connection at around 300mbits.

Hope that helps.

Comment: did this. got completely screwed. Wifi is not working at all

Comment: Reboot, hold shift key during boot until grub menu appears, select Advanced Options for Ubuntu and select a 3.13 kernel.  Download the newer version of the driver from http://packages.ubuntu.com/utopic/bcmwl-kernel-source and see if it works in the 3.18 kernel