# Wireless Not Working Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, wireless, dell, broadcom

Wireless isn't working in ubuntu 14.04, even after installing `bcmwl-kernel-source` package & enabling it via:
**Software & Update/Additional Drivers**
Also, There are no options to enable a Wireless network in System **Settings/Network**.
I work on a new Dell Inspirion 3543.

Here are the Network card details:

```
06:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [14e4:4365] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Dell Wireless 1704 802.11n + BT 4.0 [1028:0016]
    Control: I/O- Mem- BusMaster- SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 255
    Region 0: Memory at f7200000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [disabled] [size=32K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>

07:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101E/RTL8102E PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller [10ec:8136] (rev 07)
    Subsystem: Dell Device [1028:0656]
```

`dpkg -l | grep bcmwl` result:

```
ii  bcmwl-kernel-source             6.30.223.248+bdcom-0ubuntu1 

amd64        Broadcom 802.11 Linux STA wireless driver source
```

I already tried the answer:

[Drivers for Broadcom BCM43142 on Ubuntu 14.04 (Trusty Tahr)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/459654/drivers-for-broadcom-bcm43142-on-ubuntu-14-04-trusty-tahr)

But still `bcmwl-kernel-source` wouldn't install correctly, it gets installed with no **wl**!

Comment: user3305447 - is your issue solved ?

Comment: No, it isn't solved ... any suggestions?!

Comment: Add the results of `dpkg -l | grep bcmwl` to your question.  The -l is a lower case L not a 1(one)

Comment: done: `ii  bcmwl-kernel-source             6.30.223.248+bdcom-0ubuntu1 

amd64        Broadcom 802.11 Linux STA wireless driver source`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Installing Broadcom Wireless Drivers](http://askubuntu.com/q/55868/283843)

Comment: Please [run the WiFi diagnostics](/a/425205/175814) and [edit] your question to include a link to the result.

Comment: In terminal, do `sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source` and paste the output to paste.ubuntu.com and post the URL and post `cat /etc/modprobe.d/* | grep wl`

Answer (score 1):

Which kernel you are using (`uname -a`)?

I had the same problem after updating from 3.19 to 4.0 because the bcmwl-kernel-source package isn't working with 4.0 at the moment. If this is your problem, you can find more information about it (and the patch) [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/bcmwl/+bug/1424676).

**Edit:** If someone is looking for the patch and how to apply it: longsleep (the author) updated the readme section of [the project](https://github.com/longsleep/bcmwl-ubuntu) on how to build and install the package.

Comment: Kernel:
`Linux 3.16.0-30-generic #40~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jan 15 17:43:14 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

Comment: If the patch is required, Would you please explain how to use it? because I'm new to Linux.

Comment: I'm afraid that my suggestion won't work for you because of the different kernel. I found another question with the same probleme here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/459654/drivers-for-broadcom-bcm43142-on-ubuntu-14-04-trusty-tahr. Perhaps this can help you.

Comment: Thank you, I already tried this answer but still having a problem in installing `bcmwl-kernel-source` .. it gets installed but without **wl**.

Comment: What does a `sudo modprobe wl` shows? And please use the script that  David Foerster mentioned and post the results here.