# How to set up my wireless card when there is no official driver for BCM43142?

Tags: 14.04, networking, wireless, drivers, broadcom

I managed to download a driver on page [by BCM](http://www.broadcom.com/support/?gid=1)

I also tried to install `bcmwl-kernel-source` and I succeeded.

I'm now able to access internet through wireless.

But my problem is quite different from other BCM43142 users.I get offline every 3 minutes on average,but I just don't know what to do.

You know,it's really annoying that when I was typing this ,I got disconnected again.

My experience before tells me that perhaps the problem comes from the incorrect driver,but in fact I can't find a correct driver....

I googled,but there was no useful information.

Please help.Thanks

---

EDIT1:

Don't understand why I got downvotes.

Did I make it clear that I managed to install the driver?

Yes I've read [the link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/459654/drivers-for-broadcom-bcm43142-on-ubuntu-14-04-trusty-tahr) before,

but it didn't work.

The problem I've got is not trouble in installing the driver,but in that I have difficulty in consistent internet access.

I don't know how to solve this problem,so I taged with `drivers`,because I thought that could be one of the main causes.

btw,this PC works fine with Windows 8.Hate to say this,but the wireless card works fine with Windows 8.

Thanks anyway.

EDIT2:

Sorry that I don't understand what I should explain again....

But I really don't know why I just don't have a consistent wireless connection.

As I've mentioned,I've followed the steps from every list I've found to reinstall the driver I've got again and again.I managed to get access to network but I get disconnected really quickly.

Again,I'm quite sure it's not the problem of the network,as I've tried again on Windows 8,it's working fine.

Any idea is welcomed,

I'm really confused at the moment.Thanks anyway

EDIT3:

Can you please tell me the reason of your downvotes?

Is there an obvious way to solve the problem?

Please help me out of this!Thanks

Comment: That's not related to the driver. You can have bad signal strength or too many APs working at the same channel around. And the driver you've installed is an official Broadcom proprietary driver.

Comment: sorry,I didn't get that?What might be the problem then?btw,I managed to access Internet when I used Windows 8 on this PC.@pilot6 I don't think it's due to the signal strnegth or too many APs

Comment: One of these but not limited to: you are too far from AP, the signal is blocked by something, antenna of your adapter has a bad contact, there are many other APs in the neighborhood at the same channel, there is some radio interference.

Comment: Anyway there is no other working driver for this chip.

Comment: @Pilot6 Sir,sorry I didn't mention.the internet condition was fine,it's set up with a family router,and the windows 8 works fine on this PC.if it's due to  one of those reasons,how could it explain that windows is working alright? Yeah I agree,i didn't find any other way to solve this....

Comment: @BrianZ I think the problem I had is quite different!Listen,I've followed the step on that page to install the driver successfully,but now facing with another different problem!Can you help me?

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/WirelessTroubleShootingGuide - Sounds like you've covered most of these steps, but not all.

Comment: @BrianZ Sorry it took a while to finish the steps.In fact ,the settings seem to be in the right way,while the problem still isn't solved.Thanks for the link anyway....

Comment: Not the answer you are looking for I know, but honestly, I would suggest you try a different wifi card that is officially supported by Ubuntu: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/WirelessCardsSupported

Comment: Yeah I understand you,but this wifi chip comes as I buy this laptop....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't know what caused this,but as I updated all the way from 14.04 to 15.10,the problem disappeared.

Thanks for your help!