# Bluetooth broadcom 43142 unstable connection and other bugs during work

Tags: drivers, kernel, bluetooth, broadcom, firmware

I could successfully install drivers for this module thanks to [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/632336/bluetooth-broadcom-43142-isnt-working-on-ubuntu/632348#632348) answer, but there are some issues.

I need bluetooth for my keyboard, which works just fine under Windows. But with linux connection can often drop, and also very often some letters are typed much more then they needed.

Example:

```
Likkkkkkkkkke tttttttttttthhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhatt!!!!!!!!!
```

Often after that loops it disconnects. If i am  turning off the keyboard during that loop, it will still continue to type for a long time, that is why I am sure, that it is a linux drivers issue.

Any ideas please how to make work more stable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Installed Bluez 5.27 from bluez.org (newer are laggy for me) and lags gone away. Less disconnects also, but i guess it is about ubuntu's work with kernel or smth else.

Comment: I recommend [edit]ing this answer to expand it with specific details about how to do this. (See also [How do I write a good answer?](/help/how-to-answer) for general advice about what sorts of answers are considered most valuable on Ask Ubuntu.)

Answer (score 0):

If low battery charge is not the issue (which it may well be, based on Your description), one thing that *may* fix Your issue would be to try a newer kernel version.

Upgrading Your kernel may seem difficult, but it is actually fairly straight forward, provided that there are newer versions packaged and available (which is almost always the case).

To check Your current kernel version, open up a Terminal enter the following command:

```
uname -a
```

The output will look similar to this:

```
Linux {hostname removed} 4.5.2-040502-generic #201604200335 SMP Wed Apr 20 07:37:26 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

As You can see here, in my case I have chosen to upgrade to kernel version **4.5**.

Here is a guide that explains how to do this in more detail: http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2016/03/upgrade-linux-kernel-4-5-ubuntu/

Note: If You still experience issues, it could also be worth while to try uninstalling/removing the firmware mentioned in the other question that You originally linked to, as it *may* not be needed at all. I would suggest that You try experimenting with this.

Update:
I just stumbled upon this answer that may also help You out: [Drivers for Broadcom BCM43142 on Ubuntu 14.04 (Trusty Tahr)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/459654/drivers-for-broadcom-bcm43142-on-ubuntu-14-04-trusty-tahr)

Comment: Thank you for your answer!  But... Battery is ok, it works fine under Windows. I already have kernel 4.5. And that firmware IS needed. Broadcom made some very "smart" stuff. 43142 module is 2in1 wifi+bluetooth in one piece of hardware. You can enable wifi with proprietary firmware, but they did not provide it for bluetooth! And Ubuntu can see bluetooth hardware, but cannot use it until you install firmware from Windows. But even after that it is unusable for me...

Comment: ok, it seems that tuning laptop powersaving options did help a little bit.                        As my bluetooth adapter is recognised as usb device, you may have some software that reduces power on usb. For me it was tlp, and now it does not use any powersaving on bluetooth adapter. But still the problem remains.