# Wireless drivers not working on Dell Ispiron 3543

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless

I am running on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS  and my wireless drivers are not working, I've tried installing the drivers via the additional drivers option on the software & updates section but no luck. Please help my driver details are as follows:

Broadcom Corporation BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [14e4:4365] (rev 01)

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/459654/drivers-for-broadcom-bcm43142-on-ubuntu-14-04-trusty-tahr

Answer (score 0):

Install synaptic package manager and search bcm43 drivers. 
I agreee with AndroidDev, you could find the solution on the link provided by his/her answer.