# My wireless adapter's light is on but there are no options for connecting to a wireless network. Please help

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, 16.04

I am very new to Linux and have tried looking through multiple answers in order to fix my problem. Previously I didn't even have a light running on my adapter but now the light is on when running Ubuntu but still I can only connect through Ethernet.

The wireless adapter I am using is the [Link-com Archer T2U](http://www.tp-link.com/en/products/details/cat-11_Archer-T2U.html). I am running on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS on dual boot with windows.

If you have any advice it would be much appreciated.

- `lsusb` command:

  ```
  Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0bda:5728 Realtek Semiconductor Corp.
  Bus 001 Device 002: ID 148f:761a Ralink Technology, Corp.
  ```
- `uname -r`:

  ```
      4.4.0-22-generic
  ```
- `dkms status` returns nothing.
- `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` (doesn't appear to me my usb dongle):

  ```
  02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [14e4:4365] (rev 01)
      Subsystem: Lenovo BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [17aa:0611]
      Kernel driver in use: bcma-pci-bridge
  ```
- `lshw -c network`:

  ```
   *-network
         description: Ethernet interface
         product: QCA8172 Fast Ethernet
         vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
         physical id: 0
         bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
         logical name: enp1s0
         version: 10
         serial: 20:1a:06:fe:ce:bc
         size: 100Mbit/s
         capacity: 100Mbit/s
         width: 64 bits
         clock: 33MHz
         capabilities: pm pciexpress msi msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
         configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=alx duplex=full ip=10.133.203.211 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=100Mbit/s
         resources: irq:32 memory:f0100000-f013ffff ioport:2000(size=128)
    *-network
         description: Network controller
         product: BCM43142 802.11b/g/n
         vendor: Broadcom Corporation
         physical id: 0
         bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
         version: 01
         width: 64 bits
         clock: 33MHz
         capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
         configuration: driver=bcma-pci-bridge latency=0
         resources: irq:17 memory:f0000000-f0007fff
  ```
- `rfkill list all`:

  ```
  0: ideapad_wlan: Wireless LAN
      Soft blocked: no
      Hard blocked: no
  1: ideapad_bluetooth: Bluetooth
      Soft blocked: no
      Hard blocked: no
  2: hci0: Bluetooth
      Soft blocked: no
      Hard blocked: no
  ```

Comment: Please open up a terminal with ctrl + alt + t and edit your question with the output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` , `lshw -c network` and `rfkill list all`

Comment: @Promille Have updated the question with those outputs. Thanks

Comment: Great. Check the accepted answer - maybe this is of help? http://askubuntu.com/questions/459654/drivers-for-broadcom-bcm43142-on-ubuntu-14-04-trusty-tahr

Comment: Hmm problem is that is of my intergrated network adapter not the new one I just bought :/ . I also get a wl key not available when trying to install that.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean. The problem is that the TP-Link Archer T2U doesn't find any Wi-Fi networks, right? I assume the "integrated network adapter" is the ethernet card, or do you have another wireless card as well? Also, there is linux drivers for the TP-Link on their homepage: http://www.tp-link.com/lb/download/Archer-T2U_V1.html#Driver

Comment: The Archer T2U is a USB dongle. The intergrated network adapter is the one that is built into my laptop, which I believe is broadcom.

Comment: @Promille I also get the ra0 device not found error.

Comment: Please [run the network diagnostics](//askubuntu.com/a/425205/175814) and [edit] your question to include a link to the result.