# Error on sudo modprobe w1

Tags: networking, drivers, broadcom

With reference to  [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/459654/drivers-for-broadcom-bcm43142-on-ubuntu-14-04-trusty-tahr) I tried to resolve the technical problems of my Wifi and drivers, I ran the command `sudo modprobe w1`, but it gave an an error:

```
modprobe:FATAL: Module w1 not found in directory /lib/modules/4.4.0-28-generic
```

I have searched the internet but haven't found a solution to this.

My laptop can't connect to my the wifi of my hostel. However, other computers, running both Windows and Linux, can do so. When I try to connect, my laptop gets into an infinite connecting loop.

My chipset is Broadcom Corporation BCM43142 802.11b/g/n.
How can I solve this problem and what does the error message above mean?

Comment: `w1` sounds like an unlikely name for a module: did you mean `wl` (double-u ell)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Installing Broadcom Wireless Drivers](http://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers)

Comment: @steeldriver That's an answer. You should probably post that.