# Broadcom BCM43142 issues

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, 16.04, broadcom

I have an hp and BCM43142, Ubuntu 16.04, everything updated. I have `bcmwl-kernel-source`. The one available in additional drivers.

The internet works for few hours then it stops working, I'll have to log out and log in when that happens and sometimes, I must restart.

[my blacklist.conf](http://pastebin.com/HPZ0Xt0f). I tried to reinstall the driver, which presumably rebuilds it and it didn't work. I tried b43-framework and it didn't work. Isn't there a more reliable driver offered by broadcom or hp?

The output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` is

```
 lspci -knn | grep Net -A2
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Limited BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [14e4:4365] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [103c:804a]
    Kernel driver in use: wl
```

Comment: This guy seems to have the answer. Try his solution. http://askubuntu.com/a/460616/414234

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` terminal command.

Comment: @Pilot6 please check the question

Comment: The driver is correctly installed. This must be some hardware problem, or a problem with this driver. I have no suggestions except replacing the wireless adapter.

Comment: Well havent happened to me yet...

Comment: @Pilot6 if the issue cant be solved im gonna have to reinstall windows 10 on the pc, as much as I hate it, it worked with bcm

Comment: Try `broadcom-sta-dkms` instead of `bcmwl-kernel-source`. It looks like it is a new driver.

Comment: @Pilot6 seems to have worked, will have to test drive it for 2 days and ill report back

Comment: @still the same problem, disconnecting every now and then

Comment: I exactly have the same problem with my Pavilion15, it seems this BCM43142 chip is problematic,   as it is described in the driver of bcmwl-kernel-source:
Description: Broadcom 802.11 Linux STA wireless driver source
 This package contains Broadcom 802.11 Linux STA wireless driver
 for use with Broadcom's BCM4311-, BCM4312-, BCM4313-, BCM4321-,
 BCM4322-, BCM43224-, and BCM43225-, BCM43227- and BCM43228-based
 hardware.
you see there is no bcm43142 listed