# Ubuntu 18.04 WiFi problem (Broadcom BCM43142)

Tags: wireless, 18.04, broadcom

My laptop is HP Pavilion 15 p077. I cannot use my internal WiFi adapter very well. When I'm entering in other rooms, my WiFi is not connecting. So I bought TP link TL-WN725N. But problem is not gone. When I used Windows, I used my WiFi. What's the problem? I didn't found my solution in any of topics.

How can I use either internal or external WiFi adapter without any problem?

Output of `lspci -nnk | grep -A3 0280`:

```
08:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [14e4:4365] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [103c:2230]
    Kernel driver in use: wl
    Kernel modules: wl
```

Comment: What is the output of `lspci -nnk | grep -A3 0280`?

Comment: Sir I edited and putted result into the topic

Comment: @bummi did you really think It's regdomain problem?

Comment: [This](https://askubuntu.com/q/459654) might help