# Bluetooth always searchs for devices but never finds any devices

Tags: drivers, 18.04, bluetooth

I ran this command:

```
$ lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net; lsusb; rfkill list all; dmesg | egrep -i 'blue|firm'
02:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 15)
Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [103c:80e5]
Kernel driver in use: r8169
Kernel modules: r8169
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [14e4:4365] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [103c:804a]
    Kernel driver in use: wl
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 138a:0050 Validity Sensors, Inc. Swipe Fingerprint Sensor
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0a5c:216d Broadcom Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 05c8:0379 Cheng Uei Precision Industry Co., Ltd (Foxlink) 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: brcmwl-0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
[    0.028000] Spectre V2 : Enabling Restricted Speculation for firmware calls
[    0.066870] ACPI: [Firmware Bug]: BIOS _OSI(Linux) query ignored
[    5.319120] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[    5.319135] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[    5.319137] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[    5.319139] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[    5.319143] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[    5.703421] [drm] Finished loading DMC firmware i915/skl_dmc_ver1_26.bin (v1.26)
[    5.722151] [Firmware Bug]: ACPI(PXSX) defines _DOD but not _DOS
[    5.808987] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: chip id 70
[    5.809799] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: features 0x06
[    5.825782] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM43142A
[    5.825785] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM (001.001.011) build 0000
[    5.826014] bluetooth hci0: Direct firmware load for brcm/BCM.hcd failed with error -2
[    5.826016] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: Patch brcm/BCM.hcd not found
[    7.840031] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x1003 tx timeout
[    7.962467] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[    7.962469] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[    7.962472] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[   13.532093] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[   13.532098] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[   13.532103] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
[ 9003.483680] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x1003 tx timeout
```

can someone pls help me it keeps searching fr devices but never finds any devices?

Comment: See here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/459654/drivers-for-broadcom-bcm43142-on-ubuntu-14-04-trusty-tahr Did you install `bcmwl-kernel-source`?

Comment: yes i did still it didnt work