# 5GHz frequency available but networks not showing up

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, frequency

My laptop has 5GHz support for Wi-Fi but 5GHz networks are not showing up. Only 2.4 Ghz networks are being listed.

5GHz networks are working perfectly in Windows. In Ubuntu, they're not showing up.

My output of `iwlist <interface> freq` is :

```
wlp6s0    32 channels in total; available frequencies :
          Channel 01 : 2.412 GHz
          Channel 02 : 2.417 GHz
          Channel 03 : 2.422 GHz
          Channel 04 : 2.427 GHz
          Channel 05 : 2.432 GHz
          Channel 06 : 2.437 GHz
          Channel 07 : 2.442 GHz
          Channel 08 : 2.447 GHz
          Channel 09 : 2.452 GHz
          Channel 10 : 2.457 GHz
          Channel 11 : 2.462 GHz
          Channel 12 : 2.467 GHz
          Channel 13 : 2.472 GHz
          Channel 14 : 2.484 GHz
          Channel 36 : 5.18 GHz
          Channel 38 : 5.19 GHz
          Channel 40 : 5.2 GHz
          Channel 42 : 5.21 GHz
          Channel 44 : 5.22 GHz
          Channel 46 : 5.23 GHz
          Channel 48 : 5.24 GHz
          Channel 52 : 5.26 GHz
          Channel 56 : 5.28 GHz
          Channel 60 : 5.3 GHz
          Channel 64 : 5.32 GHz
          Channel 100 : 5.5 GHz
          Channel 104 : 5.52 GHz
          Channel 108 : 5.54 GHz
          Channel 112 : 5.56 GHz
          Channel 116 : 5.58 GHz
          Channel 120 : 5.6 GHz
          Channel 124 : 5.62 GHz
          Current Frequency:2.412 GHz (Channel 1)
```

What's the exact problem? And  how to troubleshoot it?
Any help will be greatly appreciated.

P.S. I downloaded drivers from `bcwml-kernel-source`

Edit :
I'm using Ubuntu Desktop 20.04 Focal Fossa LTS Release. I don't know about the stack details. My Network Controller is Broadcom BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [14e4:4365] (rev 01)

Comment: I would start by working out your OS & release details (we don't know that), if using a LTS release, which stack choice you've made may also be helpful (are you using the GA or HWE stack? which are selected by ISO used to install if desktop, or during installation if server... we don't have such details unless you provide them).  *Software stack age provide a huge clue and allow you to evaluate issues with given hardware, details you should know that we don't unless provided*

Comment: I have updated the question! I don't know which stack I am using. I continued with the default options during installation.

Comment: The *stack* details is a fancy way of giving details such as your release.  Since 20.04 LTS is a *long-term-support* release, two stacks are offered; Desktop defaults to using the HWE stack (*unless changed by user post-install*) where as Server defaults to GA but gives the user the option during install (*or post-install*) to change it. You didn't say if desktop, server so didn't provide full details; probably a HWE stack so you'll be using the 5.8 kernel, but that's a guess and it's best if we're not guessing (*drivers* are kernel modules; thus the stack in use is very important!).

Comment: Ok, I'm using Desktop. So, it is HWE stack then.

Comment: You might want to consult this article: https://askubuntu.com/questions/459654/drivers-for-broadcom-bcm43142-on-ubuntu-14-04-trusty-tahr

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. But, I have installed only one driver. That too not manually, but from the firmware update. My problem is not due to repeated drivers.