# Wireless not being detected at all 12.04 Inspiron 15R

Tags: 12.04, wireless, drivers

I have a Dell Inspiron 15R that came preinstalled with Windows 8.1
I just installed Ubuntu 12.04 in dual boot and got it working.
Now i cannot connect to wifi.
I tried [How do I install BCM43142 wireless drivers for Dell Vostro 3460/3560?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/175104/how-do-i-install-bcm43142-wireless-drivers-for-dell-vostro-3460-3560)
and also other methods involving installing firmware-b43-installer and b43-fwcutter.
Nothing works.
rfkill list all only shows Bluetooth:

```
rfkill list all
```

0: hci0: Bluetooth

```
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no
```

vipluv@Krishnakshetra:~$

My wireless hardware isn't detected at all!
What do i do?

EDIT:

output for lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net:

```
    01:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101E/RTL8102E PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller [10ec:8136] (rev 07)
        Subsystem: Dell Device [1028:05e9]
        Kernel driver in use: r8169

02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [14e4:4365] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Dell Wireless 1704 802.11n + BT 4.0 [1028:0016]
    Kernel driver in use: bcma-pci-bridge
```

and for iwconfig:

```
eth0      no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.
```

Comment: Please add the following output to your question via the edit button: `lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net` and `iwconfig`

Comment: @ElderGeek is that ok?

Comment: Have you tried @izx answer here?: http://askubuntu.com/questions/175104/how-do-i-install-bcm43142-wireless-drivers-for-dell-vostro-3460-3560?lq=1 without the other modifications you did?

Comment: It appears this bug was fixed: see here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/bcmwl/+bug/923809/comments/15

Comment: Please also provide the output of `ubuntu-drivers devices` and `ubuntu-drivers debug`

Answer (score 0):

Step one: Connect your system to the network temporarily using an Ethernet cable.

Step two: Open a terminal and issue the commands:
`sudo apt-get update`
and then after that completes,
`sudo apt-get upgrade`

Step three:

Open Additional Drivers and install what is recommended. If there aren't any needed or recommended you'll see this:

[image: additionaldrivers]

If your wireless hardware isn't detected at all, consider trying a USB wifi adapter as the integrated one may be damaged somehow.

Comment: I installed the drivers...
Now it says 'Activated but not in use'
and still refuses to detect the wifi.
Any tips?

Comment: Insure wireless networking is activated and the indicator led for your wireless is on.

Comment: I had done that back then, as well! :-/
I tried a hundred different things after that, then gave up.
My ubuntu still doesn't detect wireless. 
It's been a while, i know, but could you still help?

Comment: Expanded answer - without knowing the "hundred things" you've tried it's hard to say which helped and which made things worse....