# Ethernet and wifi not working after package update 12.04 LTS

Tags: 12.04, wireless, network-manager, wired

Recently I updated some packages in my Dell vostro 2520 laptop and after that my broadcom network driver is not working. When listing details of this network card with `sudo lshw -C Network` it shows `UNCLAIMED`. No wired and wifi connections work.

Here is the output of `lspci`:

```
07:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [14e4:4365] (rev 01)
09:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 07)
```

I was able to connect to ethernet after typing `modprobe 8169`. Below are the results from the other commands.

```
siva@siva-Vostro-2520:~$ ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr e0:db:55:c7:ff:3f  
      inet addr:10.10.10.109  Bcast:10.10.10.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      inet6 addr: fe80::e2db:55ff:fec7:ff3f/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:84 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:79 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:8514 (8.5 KB)  TX bytes:15491 (15.4 KB)
      Interrupt:44 Base address:0xc000 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
      inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
      inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
      UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
      RX packets:34 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:34 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
      RX bytes:2690 (2.6 KB)  TX bytes:2690 (2.6 KB)

siva@siva-Vostro-2520:~$ sudo ethtool -s eth0 speed 100 autoneg off
siva@siva-Vostro-2520:~$ dmesg | grep -e eth0 -e r816
[   82.540591] r8169 Gigabit Ethernet driver 2.3LK-NAPI loaded
[   82.540628] r8169 0000:09:00.0: PCI INT A -> GSI 17 (level, low) -> IRQ 17
[   82.540703] r8169 0000:09:00.0: setting latency timer to 64
[   82.540798] r8169 0000:09:00.0: irq 44 for MSI/MSI-X
[   82.541504] r8169 0000:09:00.0: eth0: RTL8168evl/8111evl at 0xffffc9000031c000, e0:db:55:c7:ff:3f, XID 0c900800 IRQ 44
[   82.541509] r8169 0000:09:00.0: eth0: jumbo features [frames: 9200 bytes, tx checksumming: ko]
[   82.542017] r8169 0000:09:00.0: PME# enabled
[   82.609758] r8169 0000:09:00.0: PME# disabled
[   82.734342] r8169 0000:09:00.0: eth0: link down
[   82.734349] r8169 0000:09:00.0: eth0: link down
[   82.734519] ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
[   82.734739] ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
[   85.141266] r8169 0000:09:00.0: eth0: link up
[   85.141556] ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
[   95.905762] eth0: no IPv6 routers present
[  159.852995] r8169 0000:09:00.0: eth0: link down
[  162.886021] r8169 0000:09:00.0: eth0: link up
```

Comment: Please edit your question to add details of your devices from the terminal: lspci -nn | grep -e 0200 -e 0280 Thanks.

Comment: Pl. help me out. it looks like an issue for many, I tried different links, but could not find the right solution

Comment: Chili555- ethernet works after the modprobe r8169. let me know what next. Thanks a lot for showing me the way

Comment: hello Chili555, Mine is a 64 bit, Intel. So should I download the 32-bit/i386 driver?

Comment: What did the command _arch_ tell you? If it reports i686, you need the 32-bit version, which is tricky and may not work. If it reports x86_64, then you need the 64-bit version.

Comment: hello Chili555, the wifi is working well after updating the 64bit driver. just one problem now is that everytime I boot I have to type the modprobe command to get ethernet connected. what should I do?

Comment: Please see my edit below.

Comment: sorry, I should have told clearly. The loading problem is just for the ethernet/wired connection. Wireless connection works well, and loads automatically.

Comment: Oops! Please see my edit.

Comment: Great, I am all set. Thanks a lot for helping me out.

Answer (score 1):

Let's try to coax your ethernet to life first so we can use it to fix the wireless. Please hook up the ethernet with a known good cable, open a terminal and do:

```
sudo modprobe r8169
ifconfig
```

Do you have an ethernet interface, probably eth0? If so, then do:

```
sudo ethtool -s eth0 speed 100 autoneg off
```

Now does it connect? If so, we'll amend one file and make it persistent. If not, see if the logs have any clues:

```
dmesg | grep -e eth0 -e r816
```

Glad the ethernet is working! As for the wireless, in Ubuntu 12.04, it is probably impossible to get working unless you have installed a 64-bit system; check:

```
arch
```

If so, please check here: [How do I install BCM43142 wireless drivers for Dell Vostro 3460/3560?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/175104/how-do-i-install-bcm43142-wireless-drivers-for-dell-vostro-3460-3560) Otherwise, I suggest you install Ubuntu 14.04 LTS or 14.10 in which case, all you need do is:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source
```

And then reboot.

If the ethernet driver refuses to load on boot, please do:

```
sudo -i
echo r8169  >>  /etc/modules
depmod -a
exit
```

You should be all set.