# Broadcom 43142 wifi problem on HP p-011tx on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: wireless, drivers, kernel, broadcom, hp

Ubuntu 14.04 does not show wifi connection after new installation.

Device is:HP p011tx
Broadcomm 43142 802.11 adapter

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu 12.04 has an updated `bcmwl-kernel-source` package that supports BCM43142 as reported. Broadcomm 43142 is also found in Dell Vostro 3460-3560[See the [bug#923809 comment 15](https://askubuntu.com/questions/175104/how-do-i-install-bcm43142-wireless-drivers-for-dell-vostro-3460-3560/175115?s=1%7C0.3819#175115)

Run these commands when connected by ethernet or tethering to a mobile device:

```
sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-installer
sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source
```

Total data required was about 20-30 mB...