# WiFi drivers not compatible(new Installation-Ubuntu 16.04 LTS)

Tags: wireless, 16.04, broadcom, hp

System: HP ab516TX

```
sudo lshw -C network
```

gives

```
*-network UNCLAIMED     
       description: Network controller
       product: BCM43142 802.11b/g/n
       vendor: Broadcom Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       version: 01
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:94100000-94107fff
```

and `lscpi`
gives

```
03:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM43142 802.11b/g/n (rev 01)
```

I have checked the following topics, they aren't helping:

[No WI-FI in Ubuntu 16.04 gnome [duplicate]](https://askubuntu.com/questions/767435/no-wi-fi-in-ubuntu-16-04-gnome)

[How do I install BCM43142 wireless drivers for Dell Vostro 3460/3560?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/175104/how-do-i-install-bcm43142-wireless-drivers-for-dell-vostro-3460-3560)

New : [Installing Broadcom Drivers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers)

@Pilot6, 
Here you go. Yes I did read both of the articles. Also disable secure boot before trying to install the recommended driver.

```
lspci -knn | grep Net -A2


03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [14e4:4365] (rev 01)
    DeviceName: Broadcom BCM43142 802.11 b/g/n 1x1Wi-Fi + BT4.0 M.2 Combo Adapter
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [103c:804a]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Installing Broadcom Wireless Drivers](http://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers)

Comment: Related: http://askubuntu.com/questions/762254/why-do-i-get-required-key-not-available-when-install-dkms-modules-in-ubuntu-16/762255?s=5|0.6999#762255

Comment: @Pilot6 I have followed the steps described at Installing Broadcom Wireless Drivers. No dice, the driver is not detected. Any ideas why?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` terminal command. Did you read the related link?

Comment: @Pilot6 Yes, I've read the articles you pointed to. PS: Edited the question to include the details. of {lspci -knn | grep Net -A2}.

PS: how do you include formatting in comments?

Comment: For code formatting in comments, you can use backticks, ie. \`some text \` will result in `some text`.

Comment: Did you run `sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source`? Did you disable SecureBoot if applicable?

Comment: @Pilot6 Yes, to both. I did however try to install `bcmwl-kernel-source`  before I had asked this question, and thus had to `--purge` it first

Comment: Did it install without errors?

Comment: derp. I did not check. Sorry for wasting your time, I'll re-install it asap(now)

Comment: @Pilot6
Ah, I've found out what the problem is: for some reason secure boot is not being disabled even after running `sudo mokutil --disable-validation` ,`mokutil --sb-state` shows `SecureBoot enabled`. Anything I can do to disable it?

Comment: Please close this question. The error was due to `mokutils` not disabling `SecureBoot`. I had to do it through the setup options at boot [This](http://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers) is a correct solution my problem