# WiFi driver for Vostro 3300

Tags: drivers, internet, iwlwifi, additional-drivers, dell-vostro

I have a [Vostro 3300](https://downloads.dell.com/manuals/all-products/esuprt_laptop/esuprt_vostro_notebook/vostro-3300_service-manual_en-us.pdf) ([tech sheet](https://downloads.dell.com/manuals/all-products/esuprt_laptop/esuprt_vostro_notebook/vostro-3300_setup%20guide_en-us.pdf)).

When I first used it I had to install the driver to connect to WiFi.

Having installed Ubuntu Desktop 18.04.4 I believe I no longer have this driver.

I have seen a [similar question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/175104/how-do-i-install-bcm43142-wireless-drivers-for-dell-vostro-3460-3560) here about a Vostro 3460 but I couldn't get the solution to work.

If I download the driver from the dell website as before, is there a way for me to install this driver using Ubuntu?

If anyone has further questions I'm happy to answer

**Edit:**

```
msk@delete:~$ lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3
12:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM4313 802.11bgn Wireless Network Adapter [14e4:4727] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Dell Inspiron M5010 / XPS 8300 [1028:0010]
    Kernel driver in use: bcma-pci-bridge
    Kernel modules: bcma
```

Also I think the answer may lie here: https://victorpalau.net/2010/09/09/vostro-3300-and-ubuntu-10-4/

However I am having trouble implementing the solution. However when not using a wired connection I too have noticed that my wirless option seems to have disappeared. I think I'm close.

**Edit2:**

Here is a full list of what I tried.

```
msk@delete:~$ sudo apt-get install linux-headers$(uname -r | grep -Po "\-[a-z].*")
[sudo] password for msk: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  linux-headers-4.15.0-76 linux-headers-4.15.0-76-generic
The following NEW packages will be installed
  linux-headers-4.15.0-76 linux-headers-4.15.0-76-generic
  linux-headers-generic
0 to upgrade, 3 to newly install, 0 to remove and 0 not to upgrade.
Need to get 12.0 MB of archives.
After this operation, 89.1 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Get:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main amd64 linux-headers-4.15.0-76 all 4.15.0-76.86 [10.9 MB]
Get:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main amd64 linux-headers-4.15.0-76-generic amd64 4.15.0-76.86 [1,106 kB]
Err:3 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main amd64 linux-headers-generic amd64 4.15.0.76.78
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.142 80]
Fetched 12.0 MB in 7s (1,829 kB/s)                                             
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux-meta/linux-headers-generic_4.15.0.76.78_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.142 80]
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
msk@delete:~$ sudo apt-get install build-essential dkms
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package build-essential is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

Package dkms is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'build-essential' has no installation candidate
E: Package 'dkms' has no installation candidate
msk@delete:~$ sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic build-essential dkms
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package build-essential is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

Package dkms is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'build-essential' has no installation candidate
E: Package 'dkms' has no installation candidate
msk@delete:~$ sudo rmmod brcmsmac
msk@delete:~$ sudo rmmod bcma
rmmod: ERROR: Module bcma is in use by: b43
msk@delete:~$ sudo modprobe wl
modprobe: FATAL: Module wl not found in directory /lib/modules/5.3.0-28-generic
msk@delete:~$ /etc/modprobe/blacklist-b43.conf add blacklist brcmsmac blacklist brcmfmac blacklist bcma
bash: /etc/modprobe/blacklist-b43.conf: No such file or directory
msk@delete:~$ sudo rmmod -f Delete
rmmod: ERROR: ../libkmod/libkmod-module.c:793 kmod_module_remove_module() could not remove 'Delete': No such file or directory
rmmod: ERROR: could not remove module Delete: No such file or directory
msk@delete:~$ sudo rmmod -f dell_laptop
msk@delete:~$ sudo rmmod -f delete
rmmod: ERROR: ../libkmod/libkmod-module.c:793 kmod_module_remove_module() could not remove 'delete': No such file or directory
rmmod: ERROR: could not remove module delete: No such file or directory
msk@delete:~$ rfkill list
msk@delete:~$ rfkill list
```

Comment: Please edit your question to add the result of the terminal command: `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Done. Let me know if there is anything else I can do.

Comment: You shouldn't have to install anything at all! Please see the duplicate.